# Como gerar registro a cada novo relacionamento entre duas entidades

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Considerando um cenário onde um **membro** possui uma **conta**, **perfil pessoal**, **perfil acadêmico** e pode variar entre **status** (entre status pre-definidos: professor, aluno e colaborador) dentro do sistema. Para cada **status**, o **perfil acadêmico** é diferente.

Seguem (teoricamente) as tabelas:

```
MEMBRO
id (PK)

MEM_CONTA
membro_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO
email (string)
username (string)
senha (string)

MEM_PERFIL
membro_id (PK) (PK) // referencia id em MEMBRO

MEM_PER_PESSOAL
perfil_id (PK) (FK) // referencia membro_id em MEM_PERFIL
nome (string)
descricao (string)
```

Agora o meu problema: como permitir que um **membro** altere seu **status** (para os possíveis **status** pré-cadastrados) e, assim sendo, crie um novo registro para dados de **perfil acadêmico** (referente ao seu **status** novo) e adicione campos adicionais em **perfil pessoal**?

Para isso, imaginei:

```
STATUS
id (PK) 
titulo (string)
descricao (string)

MEMBRO_STATUS
membro_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO
status_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em STATUS
id (FK)

MEMBRO_PERFIL_PROFESSOR
id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_STATUS

MEMBRO_PERFIL_PROFESSOR_ACADEMICO
perfil_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_PERFIL_PROFESSOR
curso (string)
nivel (string)
entrada (timestamp)
saida (timestamp)

MEMBRO_PERFIL_PROFESSOR_PESSOAL
perfil_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_PERFIL_PROFESSOR
url_lattes (string)

MEMBRO_PERFIL_ALUNO
id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_STATUS

MEMBRO_PERFIL_ALUNO_ACADEMICO
perfil_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_PERFIL_ALUNO
bolsa (string)

MEMBRO_PERFIL_ALUNO_PESSOAL
perfil_id (PK) (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_PERFIL_ALUNO
url_pessoal (string)
```

Para identificar o último **status** (status ativo) de um membro, então:

```
MEMBRO
id (PK)
status_id (FK) // referencia id em MEMBRO_STATUS
```

Sobre essa prática, tenho diversas questões:

- Usar uma terceira chave (como *id*) em uma tabela de relacionamento, é correto?
- O que a normalização de dados diz sobre isso?
- Existe outra saída para essa situação?

Comment: Se está confuso, escreva de um jeito que não é confuso. Pense, detalhe o problema. Quem sabe quando estiver fazendo isto a resposta surja naturalmente. Se não surgir pelo menos teremos uma informação menos confusa para ajudar você. O segredo para modelar corretamente é ter clareza e só quem conhece o problema é que pode ter. Pense nisto como um algoritmo. Descreva o problema passo por passo, pense em tudo que é relevante. Tem espaço, não economize. Dê uma descrição geral do problema porque pode ser que tudo esteja errado.

Comment: O que eu menos entendi é esse `id (FK)`. Todos `id`s estão confusos sobre o que é, a relação entre eles, porque tem casa que não segue o padrão dos outros.

Comment: @bigown adicionei comentários explicando a referencia de cada um

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra não ficar sem resposta.

> Usar uma terceira chave (como id) em uma tabela de relacionamento, é correto?

Não sei dizer, eu não sei pra que ele serve, ao que se refere, e mesmo perguntando não obtive resposta. Mas o nome é ruim. `id` deveria ser usado só para chame primária.

Na verdade algumas destas tabelas estão esquisitas, não tem informação alguma.

> O que a normalização de dados diz sobre isso?

Ela não diz nada em algo específico. Quem faz a modelagem deve analisar e dizer como ela está. O problema é que só pode dizer quem conhece o problemas em detalhes. A pergunta não mostra todos detalhes para fazer uma avaliação.

O que dá para ver, está tudo [normalizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101). Talvez até demais. Pode até existir em certas situações, mas é estranho ter uma tabela só com chave primária e nada mais. Piora se ela também é uma chave estrangeira. Pra que precisa disto?

Mas como eu disse, pode ser correto dentro do problema.

> Existe outra saída para essa situação?

Certamente. Algumas melhores outras piores. Mas é difícil dizer sem saber todos os requisitos.

A parte do `status` parece que está no caminho correto. Claro que precisa implementar corretamente também. Mas se eu entendi bem, onde informa qual é o `status` atual?

Alguma coisa me diz que isto pode ser feito de uma forma completamente diferente sim, mas falta informações para ter certeza.

Este parece ser um caso de problema mal definido e não de modelagem mal definida. Obviamente que a segunda estará errada quando a primeira está. Quando você não consegue explicar o problema para outras pessoas, significa que você ainda não entendeu o problema.