# O que é normalização de banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia, normalização

Eu estava conversando com alguns amigos programadores, quando eu ouvi o termo "*normalização de banco de dados*". Embora eu já tenha ouvido esse termo algumas vezes antes, não consegui compreender do que se tratava.

Surgiram algumas dúvidas:

- O que significa esse termo?
- Qualquer tipo de banco de dados (seja SQL ou NoSQL) pode usar essa tal normalização?

Outra coisa é que, ao pesquisar na internet, encontrei os termos "*normalização de dados*" e "*normalização de banco de dados*". Existe alguma diferença entre as duas coisas ("*normalização de dados*" e "*normalização de banco de dados*")? Existe um termo correto ou pode ser falado das duas formas?

<sub>Não quero mais passar vergonha ao ouvir um termo desses numa reunião e ficar sem entender :)</sub>

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101. De uma certa forma é fazer um DRY no banco de dados: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101

Comment: Essa é uma comunidade onde as perguntas funcionam de maneira a auxiliar não só a minha pessoa (que quis tirar essas dúvidas) mas outras pessoas também. Portanto, sugiro a quem deu o voto negativo mostrar algo defeituoso na pergunta, para que eu possa corrigir e, assim, ajudar a quem futuramente essa pergunta possa interessar.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

## O que é normalização?

A normalização do banco de dados é o processo de transformações na estrutura de um banco de dados que visa a eliminar redundâncias e a eliminar anomalias de inserção, atualização e exclusão.

Ao efetuar o processo de normalização os dados cadastrados no banco de dados ficarão organizados de uma forma melhor e na maioria das vezes (mas nem sempre) também ocuparão menos espaço físico. Entretanto, o processo de normalização também **sempre** (sem exceções) faz aumentar o número de tabelas e em muitos casos pode ser algo difícil de se realizar. Além disso, bancos de dados normalizados além do necessário podem ter desempenho ruim e/ou complexidade excessiva, precisando então de alguma desnormalização.

## Anomalias

A principal finalidade do processo de normalização é eliminar as anomalias de inserção, atualização e exclusão. A anomalia ocorre quando não há forma de se cadastrar alguma determinada informação sem que alguma outra informação também seja diretamente cadastrada. Por exemplo, imagine que você tenha uma tabela `funcionário` com os campos `codigo`, `nome` e `projeto`, onde a coluna `projeto` corresponda ao nome do projeto no qual um funcionário foi alocado. E então você tem os seguintes dados na tabela:

| codigo | nome | projeto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pedro | Vendas |
| 2 | Maria | Vendas |
| 3 | Carlos | Cadastro de clientes |

E então surgiu um projeto novo: O de emissão de notas fiscais. Como você cadastra esse novo projeto? A resposta é que não dá para cadastrar, pois para fazer isso você teria que ter algum funcionário nesse projeto - ou seja, temos uma anomalia de inserção.

Se no exemplo anterior, o funcionário Carlos fosse desligado da empresa e o removermos da tabela, a informação sobre o projeto de cadastro de clientes é perdida. Isso é um efeito colateral indesejado - é a anomalia de exclusão. Se no entanto ele apenas fosse remanejado para o novo projeto de notas fiscais, nós também perderíamos a informação acerca da existência do projeto de cadastro de clientes - essa é a anomalia de alteração.

O problema que origina essas anomalias é o fato de a informação do projeto estar toda dentro da tabela de funcionários, que não é o lugar dela. Se tivermos duas tabelas relacionadas (1-para-N) - funcionários e projetos - as anomalias desaparecem.

Anomalias também têm relação com o conceito de [integridade referencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166125/132).

## Primeira forma normal (1FN)

A primeira regra para eliminar as anomalias é:

> Não devem existir colunas multivaloradas.

O que é uma coluna multivalorada? É uma coluna onde é possível armazenar-se mais de um valor por registro. Por exemplo, imagine que você tenha a sua tabela de clientes assim:

| codigo | nome | telefones |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paulo | 99567-4289, 3605-4900 |
| 2 | Maria | 97223-0444 |
| 3 | Alan | - |
| 4 | Juliana | 2853-0266, 96610-5480, 2410-9941 |

Observe que a coluna de telefones é multivalorada. Inserir, atualizar e excluir telefones nesse esquema é algo complicado de se fazer. Pesquisar por algum número de telefone específico também é algo complicado. A solução para isso é dividir em duas tabelas:

Cliente:

| codigo | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Paulo |
| 2 | Maria |
| 3 | Alan |
| 4 | Juliana |

Telefone:

| codigo | codigo_cliente | numero |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 99567-4289 |
| 2 | 1 | 3605-4900 |
| 3 | 2 | 97223-0444 |
| 4 | 4 | 2853-0266 |
| 5 | 4 | 96610-5480 |
| 6 | 4 | 2410-9941 |

Ao eliminar-se todas as colunas multivaloradas, o banco de dados atinge uma forma estrutural denominada de *primeira forma normal - 1FN* (*first normal form - 1NF*). Note que em português é **FN**, mas em inglês é **NF**.

## Chaves candidatas, superchaves e dependências funcionais

Antes de prosseguir com as demais formas normais, faz-se necessário introduzir-se os conceitos de chaves candidatas, superchaves e dependências funcionais.

A chave primária (*primary key*, ou apenas **PK**) é aquele conjunto de colunas que serve para identificar a tupla de uma forma única (pode ser só uma coluna, ou podem ser duas ou mais). É importante que o projetista do banco de dados saiba identificar quais são as colunas mais apropriadas para serem eleitas como parte da chave primária. Muitas vezes, uma coluna com um código numérico sequencial pode servir para ser a chave primária, mas há várias situações onde esse não é o caso.

Às vezes, há mais do que um conjunto de colunas que poderia ser chave primária. Cada um desses conjuntos é chamado de chave candidata. Por exemplo, em uma tabela `Pessoa` que tenha os campos `CPF`, `RG`, `Estado`, `Nome` e `Data_nasc`, tanto o `CPF` quanto o `RG`+`Estado` são chaves candidatas.

Assim, é possível chegar-se ao `Nome` a partir do `CPF`, mas também é possível chegar-se ao `Nome` a partir do `RG` e do `Estado`. Da mesma forma, é possível chegar-se ao valor da `Data_nasc` de uma pessoa a partir do seu `CPF` ou a partir do `RG`+`Estado`.

Por outro lado, não é possível chegar-se ao `Nome` de uma pessoa a partir apenas da `Data_nasc`, pois esse campo sozinho é insuficiente para identificar de forma única um registro da tabela, ou seja, o campo `Data_nasc` isoladamente não é uma chave.

E isso é uma dependência funcional, quando um campo pode ser alcançado a partir de outros campos. Ou seja, uma vez que chegamos no `Nome` a partir do `CPF`, então existe uma dependência funcional `CPF`→`Nome`. Também existem as dependências funcionais `RG`+`Estado`→`Nome`, `CPF`→`Data_nasc`, `RG`+`Estado`→`Data_nasc` e até mesmo `CPF`→`RG`, `CPF`→`Estado` e `RG`+`Estado`→`CPF`. Mas não existe a dependência funcional `Data_nasc`→`Nome`, pois o campo `Data_nasc` sozinho de uma pessoa é insuficiente para determinarmos de forma única qual é o nome dessa pessoa.

Qualquer conjunto de colunas que tenha como subconjunto, uma chave candidata é denominado de superchave. Ou seja, se `RG`+`Estado`+`Nome` é um exemplo de uma superchave, embora não seja uma chave candidata, vez que a chave candidata neste caso é apenas `RG`+`Estado`.

## Segunda forma normal (2FN)

A 2FN é aquela que diz que:

> Todas as colunas devem ter dependência funcional com a totalidade de cada chave candidata.

Na maioria dos casos por "*cada chave candidata*", entenda-se por "*com a chave primária*", exceto se houver mais do que uma chave candidata.

Além disso, para que uma tabela esteja na 2FN, ela deve estar antes de tudo na 1FN.

Uma coluna está em dependência funcional com a chave primária quando ela é determinada no domínio da aplicação por meio da chave primária. Uma coluna não tem dependência funcional com a chave primária quando ela é definida de forma independente da chave primária ou quando ela é definida a partir de alguma outra coluna que não seja a chave primária.

Uma dependência funcional pode ser dita estar na totalidade da chave primária quando todos os campos da chave primária são necessários para estabelecer-se a relação de dependência. No caso de a chave primária ser composta, é possível se ter uma dependência parcial.

Para dar um exemplo da 2FN, imagine que sua empresa tenha representantes comerciais atuando em clientes e queira representar a relação de quais representantes comerciais atuam em quais clientes. Nessa tabela (vamos chamar de `representação`), temos as colunas `nome_cli` para o nome do cliente e `nome_repr` para o nome do representante como chaves primárias e temos também as colunas `end_repr` para o endereço do representante, `end_cli` para o endereço do cliente e `valor_contrato`. Ou seja:

Representação:

| nome_cli (PK) | nome_repr (PK) | end_repr | end_cli | valor_contrato |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Luís | Cleyton | Rua A 888 | Rua X 123 | R$ 500,00 |
| Paula | Lara | Rua B 999 | Rua Y 345 | R$ 900,00 |
| Paula | Cleyton | Rua A 888 | Rua Y 345 | R$ 650,00 |

Observe que as colunas `end_repr` e `end_cli` dependem da chave primária. Mas eles não dependem de **toda** a chave primária, cada um depende apenas de parte dela. A solução neste caso é ter uma tabela de clientes (com o endereço do cliente), uma tabela de representantes comerciais (com o endereço dele também) e deixar na tabela de atuação as respectivas chaves estrangeiras com o valor do contrato. Ou seja:

Clientes:

| nome_cli (PK) | end_cli |
| --- | --- |
| Luís | Rua X 123 |
| Paula | Rua Y 345 |

Representantes:

| nome_repr (PK) | end_repr |
| --- | --- |
| Cleyton | Rua A 888 |
| Lara | Rua B 999 |

Representação:

| nome_cli (PK) | nome_repr (PK) | valor_contrato |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Luís | Cleyton | R$ 500,00 |
| Paula | Lara | R$ 900,00 |
| Paula | Cleyton | R$ 650,00 |

## Terceira forma normal (3FN)

A 3FN é aquela que diz que:

> Todas as colunas devem ter dependência funcional com a totalidade de cada chave candidata e nada mais além do que essas chaves candidatas.

Novamente, na maioria dos casos por "*cada chave candidata*", entenda-se por "*com a chave primária*", exceto se houver mais do que uma chave candidata. Se a única chave candidata existente for a chave primária, isso ficaria assim:

> Todas as colunas devem ter dependência funcional com a totalidade da chave primária e nada mais além da chave primária.

Além disso, para uma tabela estar na 3FN, ela deve estar primeiramente na 2FN (e também na 1FN). A parte de depender da totalidade de cada chave candidata é abordada na segunda forma normal, então o foco aqui é depender de nada mais que essas chaves.

Por exemplo. Imagine a tabela de carros com as colunas `placa` (chave primária), `cor`, `nome_proprietário`, `endereço_proprietário`:

| placa (PK) | cor | nome_proprietário | endereço_proprietário |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABX-1234 | azul | José | Rua X, 123 |
| NNU-5566 | verde | Marcos | Rua exemplo, 5678 |
| SGH-7210 | preto | Maria | Avenida teste, 7743 |
| ERT-6902 | vermelho | José | Rua X, 123 |
| BGH-5431 | preto | José | Rua X, 123 |

Observe o endereço do proprietário - ele é uma violação da 3FN, vez que é definido a partir de quem é o proprietário e não a partir da PK que é a placa do carro. Se o José mudar de endereço e atualizarmos o endereço de apenas um dos carros dele, o banco de dados ficará inconsistente (há anomalia de alteração). Se a Maria comprar mais um novo carro e adicionarmos com um outro endereço, também ficará inconsistente (anomalia de inserção). Se o Marcos vender o carro dele, o seu endereço será esquecido (anomalia de exclusão). A solução novamente, é separar em duas tabelas:

Carro:

| placa (PK) | cor | proprietário |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABX-1234 | azul | 1 |
| NNU-5566 | verde | 2 |
| SGH-7210 | preto | 3 |
| ERT-6902 | vermelho | 1 |
| BGH-5431 | preto | 1 |

Proprietário:

| codigo (PK) | nome | endereço |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | José | Rua X, 123 |
| 2 | Marcos | Rua exemplo, 5678 |
| 3 | Maria | Avenida teste, 7743 |

## Forma normal de Boyce-Codd (BCNF)

Existe uma forma normal que é um pouco mais forte que a 3FN, mas que não é requisito necessário para atingir-se a 4FN (ou mesmo a 6FN). [Essa é a forma normal de Boyce-Codd (BCNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form), também chamada por vezes de **3.5NF** ou de forma normal de Boyce-Codd-Heath.

É bem raro encontrar-se casos de tabelas que estejam na 3FN, mas não na BCFN. Além disso, existem casos (incomuns) onde essa forma normal é impossível de ser atingida (diferentemente das formas entre a 1FN a e a 6FN, que sempre podem ser atingidas).

A diferença aparece quando há mais do que uma chave candidata e elas têm alguma intersecção. A ideia é que os campos que são chaves candidatas sempre determinem os demais campos, e nunca sejam determinados por esses. Assim sendo, na BCFN não é permitido chegar-se a uma chave candidata com base em alguma outra chave candidata por meio de dependências funcionais.

[Pegando o exemplo emprestado de uma resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438829/540552), vamos dizer que cada pizza pode ter várias coberturas diferentes, cada uma de um tipo diferente e que você tem dois tipos de pizzas com essas coberturas:

| Pizza | Cobertura | Tipo de cobertura |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | muçarela | queijo |
| 1 | pepperoni | carne |
| 1 | azeitonas | vegetal |
| 2 | muçarela | carne |
| 2 | linguiça | queijo |
| 2 | pimenta | vegetal |

Há duas chaves candidatas aí: (a) Pizza e tipo de cobertura definem a cobertura. (b) Pizza e cobertura definem o tipo da cobertura.

Note que para qualquer que seja a chave candidata que nós olhamos, a demais coluna depende da totalidade da chave candidata e de nada mais do que a chave candidata, então a 3FN foi atingida.

Bem, tem algo errado aí, pois linguiça não é um queijo e muçarela não pode ser carne e queijo ao mesmo tempo - apesar de termos atingido a 3FN, ainda temos anomalias!

A solução é novamente dividir em duas tabelas:

| Pizza (PK) | Cobertura (PK) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | muçarela |
| 1 | pepperoni |
| 1 | azeitonas |
| 2 | muçarela |
| 2 | linguiça |
| 2 | pimenta |

| Cobertura (PK) | Tipo da cobertura |
| --- | --- |
| muçarela | queijo |
| pepperoni | carne |
| azeitonas | vegetal |
| linguiça | carne |
| pimenta | vegetal |

## Quarta forma normal (4FN)

É raro encontrar-se casos de tabelas que estejam na 3FN, mas não na 4FN. A 4FN concerne em anomalias existentes na relação entre diferentes colunas da chave primária, e só se aplica em tabelas com chaves primárias compostas por três colunas ou mais.

Tabelas que representem relacionamentos ternários, quaternários ou n-ários de muitos-para-muitos são locais onde vale dar-se uma olhada em possíveis violações da 4FN.

Para uma tabela estar na 4FN, ela tem que primeiramente estar também na 3FN. A BCNF não é necessária.

É meio difícil de se explicar, mas imagine que tenhamos o caso de representantes comerciais atuando em clientes, onde vários representantes podem atuar em vários clientes e que tenhamos contratos de prestação de serviços em que vários representantes atuam em vários contratos. E então temos a seguinte tabela, onde todas as colunas são chave primária:

| representante | contrato | cliente |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Geraldo | 1 | loja de roupas |
| Geraldo | 1 | hospital |
| Geraldo | 2 | loja de roupas |
| Geraldo | 2 | hospital |
| Marta | 1 | supermercado |
| Marta | 1 | hospital |
| Marta | 3 | supermercado |
| Marta | 3 | hospital |
| Luís | 2 | loja de roupas |
| Luís | 2 | supermercado |
| Luís | 4 | loja de roupas |
| Luís | 4 | supermercado |

Observe que temos relações de muitos-para-muitos entre representantes e contratos e entre representantes e clientes. Mas não temos entre clientes e contratos!

Nesta tabela, nós temos informações redundantes. Por exemplo, a informação que Marta está no contrato 1 aparece duas vezes. Se deletássemos a tupla Marta-1-hospital, teríamos uma anomalia de exclusão, vez que Marta atua no hospital (contrato 3) e Marta está no contrato 1 (no supermercado). Também temos uma anomalia de inserção no caso de tivermos algum representante alocado para algum contrato no qual não haja ainda nenhum cliente.

O ideal é separar em duas tabelas, uma com a relação entre representantes e clientes e outra com a representação entre representantes e contratos:

| representantes | contratos |
| --- | --- |
| Geraldo | 1 |
| Geraldo | 2 |
| Marta | 1 |
| Marta | 3 |
| Luís | 2 |
| Luís | 4 |

| representantes | clientes |
| --- | --- |
| Geraldo | loja de roupas |
| Geraldo | hospital |
| Marta | supermercado |
| Marta | hospital |
| Luís | loja de roupas |

## Quinta forma normal (5FN)

A 5FN é mais restrita que a 4FN, e também se aplica à tabelas com 3 ou mais colunas na chave primária. Novamente, para que a 5FN seja atingida, é necessário atingir-se a 4FN primeiramente.

Um nome alternativo para a 5FN é *projection–join normal form - PJNF* (forma normal de projeção-função).

Vamos imaginar um caso semelhante ao que usei na 4FN, mas que dessa vez além de existir a relação entre representantes e clientes e entre representantes e contratos, também temos a relação entre clientes e contratos. Dessa forma, temos essa tabela:

| representante | contrato | cliente |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Geraldo | 1 | loja de roupas |
| Geraldo | 1 | hospital |
| Geraldo | 2 | loja de roupas |
| Marta | 1 | hospital |
| Marta | 3 | supermercado |
| Marta | 3 | hospital |
| Luís | 2 | loja de roupas |
| Luís | 4 | supermercado |

Observe que essa tabela é diferente daquela que usamos na 4FN. Há algumas redundâncias, como por exemplo ela diz duas vezes que Geraldo está na loja de roupas e que o contrato 1 é aplicado ao hospital. A técnica usada para colocarmos na 4FN não se aplica, pois para quaisquer duas colunas obtidas da chave, existe uma relação (ou seja, temos a relação contrato-cliente também). Assim, essa relação já está na 4FN, mas ainda há espaço para normalização. Ao decompormos ela em três relações diferentes, chegamos a 5FN:

| representantes | contratos |
| --- | --- |
| Geraldo | 1 |
| Geraldo | 2 |
| Marta | 1 |
| Marta | 3 |
| Luís | 2 |
| Luís | 4 |

| representantes | clientes |
| --- | --- |
| Geraldo | loja de roupas |
| Geraldo | hospital |
| Marta | supermercado |
| Marta | hospital |
| Luís | loja de roupas |
| Luís | supermercado |

| contratos | clientes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | loja de roupas |
| 1 | hospital |
| 2 | loja de roupas |
| 3 | supermercado |
| 3 | hospital |
| 4 | supermercado |

## Sexta forma normal (6FN)

Para uma tabela chegar a 6FN, ela primeiramente deve estar na 5FN. Ela dita que:

> Toda tabela só pode ter uma ou nenhuma coluna que não seja parte da chave primária.

Encontrar casos onde a 5FN foi atingida mas a 6FN não foi, é fácil: Qualquer tabela com duas ou mais colunas que não sejam chave primária são uma violação da 6FN!

Entretanto, encontrar-se casos onde a 6FN faça sentido de ser aplicada e traga algum benefício real com isso é bem raro - na maior parte dos casos aplicá-la acaba sendo maluquice, pois a aplicação desta forma normal tende a produzir uma explosão no número de tabelas sem trazer nenhum ou quase nenhum benefício com isso. A 6FN não foi definida para ser algo útil na prática, ela tem mais a finalidade de ser um limite teórico que defina qual é o ponto final a partir do qual nenhuma outra normalização seria possível.

Para ver como seria o processo aqui (e também duvidar de qualquer benefício real que isso traga), imagine a tabela `pessoa` com os campos `codigo` (chave primária), `nome` (`NOT NULL`), `sexo` (`NOT NULL`) e `cor_favorita` (`NULLABLE`), e tenhamos esses registros:

| codigo (PK) | nome | sexo | cor_favorita |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Marcela | F | verde |
| 2 | Rodolfo | M | - |
| 3 | Tiago | M | amarelo |

Ela seria decomposta assim:

Pessoa-nome:

| codigo (PK) | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Marcela |
| 2 | Rodolfo |
| 3 | Tiago |

Pessoa-sexo:

| codigo (PK) | sexo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | F |
| 2 | M |
| 3 | M |

Pessoa-cor-favorita:

| codigo (PK) | cor_favorita |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | verde |
| 3 | amarelo |

Observe que cada coluna que não fazia parte de chave primária acabou indo parar em uma tabela separada. Observe também que a tabela `pessoa-cor-favorita` não tem um registro para o elemento 2 (o Rodolfo). Essa forma de normalização elimina a necessidade de se ter `NULLABLE` em colunas, e todas as colunas resultantes são `NOT NULL`. Os casos das colunas que eram nulos simplesmente acabaram sendo omitidos dos registros resultantes.

## Forma normal de domínio-chave (DKNF)

A forma normal de domínio-chave (*domain-key normal form*) é a que dita que:

> Todas as restrições de integridade do banco de dados devem ser impostas ou por restrições de chave ou por restrições de valores de domínio.

Por restrições de chave, entende-se chaves primárias (PK), chaves estrangeiras (FK) e chaves únicas (UK). Por valores de domínio entende-se o conjunto de valores válidos para cada determinada coluna.

Esta forma normal é bem forte, sendo mais forte que a 5FN+BCNF. Porém, ela não é mais forte que a 6NF, uma vez que permite a existência de várias colunas que não sejam parte da chave primária em uma mesma tabela e nem a 6NF é mais forte que ela, uma vez que não há mecanismo na 6FN que garante que todas as restrições de integridade sejam modeladas tal como exige a DKNF.

Esta forma normal é o nirvana, a utopia, o estado ideal e perfeito da normalização. Entretanto, na prática, é quase impossível de se atingi-la porque qualquer banco de dados com regras de negócio com alguma complexidade provavelmente vai ter algum tipo de regra de consistência que não tem como ser modelada apenas como restrições de chave ou de valores de domínio. Entretanto, mesmo quando inatingível, um esforço para chegar próximo a ela é válido por eliminar várias possibilidades de anomalias.

## Outras formas normais

### Forma não-normalizada (UNF)

Ah, e é claro, temos também a forma não-normalizada (*Unnormalized form - UNF*), que é aquela forma que não se adequa nem mesmo a 1FN. Aqui é o vale-tudo. Pode ser desde aquela coluna multivalorada com vários números de telefones até aquela planilha gigante no excel com dezenas de tipos de informações diferentes todas misturadas em um tabelão só e cheio de Ctrl+C Ctrl+V e infestado de anomalias.

Entretanto, apesar de ser o vale-tudo, existem situações onde a UNF aplicada de forma inteligente pode ser vantajosa e muitas bases NoSQL se aproveitam disso.

### Forma normal de chave elementar (EKNF)

Existe um algoritmo publicado (algoritmo de Barnstein) para se normalizar tabelas e levá-las até a 3FN. Porém, pesquisas realizadas posteriormente descobriram que esse algoritmo é um pouquinho mais rígido do que a 3FN exige, mas ainda sem satisfazer a BCNF ou a 4FN. Por esse motivo, essa forma normal foi chamada de [forma normal de chave elementar (*elementary key normal form - EKNF*)](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/%7Ezaniolo/papers/tods82b.pdf).

Segundo esse artigo:

> Uma relação R está na EKNF se para cada dependência funcional elementar de R, então X→A, sendo (a) X uma chave de R ou (b) A um atributo elementar chave de R.

Na prática, a diferença para a 3FN é mínima. E sempre que a BCNF for atingida, a EKNF também já vai ter sido.

### Forma normal de tupla essencial (ETNF)

Uma outra forma normal existente, mais forte que a 4FN+BCNF, porém mais fraca que a 5FN+BCNF é a [forma normal de tupla essencial (*essential tuple normal form - ETNF*)](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-fagin/icdt12.pdf). Os autores que definiram essa forma normal a colocam como uma alternativa para a 5FN, que embora seja mais fraca, seria tão efetiva quanto.

Para a ETNF ser atingida, primeiro a BCNF tem que ser atingida. Então, a ETNF dita que:

> Algum componente de cada FK explicitamente declarada é uma superchave.

Os autores que definiram a ETNF também se referem a outros trabalhos que definem a *forma normal de superchaves* (*superkey normal form - SKNF*), a *forma normal livre de redundâncias* (*redundancy-free normal form - RFNF*) e *forma normal de chave completa* (*key-complete normal form - KCNF*).

A 5FN+BCNF é mais forte que a SKNF que é mais forte que a RFNF que é mais forte que a ETNF que é mais forte que a 4FN+BCNF. Também é demonstrado que a KCNF é igual a RFNF, embora tenham sido definidas por pessoas diferentes e de formas diferentes. Ou seja, todas essas formas são formas intermediárias entre a 4FN+BCNF e a 5FN+BCNF.

Entretanto, nenhuma dessas formas normais menos conhecidas é muito relevante para quem só está querendo modelar a sua aplicação de banco de dados, até porque é bem raro de se encontrar algum caso onde a 4FN foi atingida e 5FN não foi, e mesmo quando esses casos sejam encontrados, bastaria aplicar a normalização para 5FN ao invés de tentar um estado intermediário entre a 4FN e a 5FN. Essas formas só são relevantes para quem está fazendo alguma pesquisa teórica na área, ou está construindo alguma ferramenta de modelagem de banco de dados, ou tem alguma necessidade muita específica nisso.

## Até onde normalizar?

Em geral, muitos ficam satisfeitos em atingir a terceira forma normal e não se preocupam muito com as demais formas normais superiores a essa porque:

- Se aplicam a casos raros, pois quando a 3FN é atingida, quase sempre a BCNF, a 4FN e a 5FN também foram por sorte ou acidente. Isso ocorre porque é difícil se ter um caso na 3FN que não está na BCNF e também porque tabelas com três ou mais colunas na chave primária e que tenham relações de dependência entre essas colunas são algo bem raro.
- Uma vez que a 3FN é atingida (e provavelmente, por sorte ou acidente, a BCNF, a 4FN e a 5FN também), restam bem poucas possibilidades que permitam a introdução de anomalias. Procurar atingir a 6FN é em geral maluquice e não traz benefício prático algum. Procurar atingir a DKFN é quase sempre impossível, embora essa busca possa ser valiosa ao revelar ainda alguma possibilidade de anomalia que possa ser eliminada.
- Por vezes, para melhorar-se o desempenho do banco de dados ou simplificar-se a sua estrutura, a recomendação acaba sendo a de desnormalizar algumas coisas. Muitos sistemas com foco em *dataware house* ou *business intelligence* são normalizados só até a 2FN, mesmo tendo sido concebidos a partir de estruturas que já estavam na 3FN e foram desnormalizadas.
- Aliás, a 6FN tem mais utilidade quando se pensa em desnormalização ao invés de normalização. A ideia seria procurar tabelas com relacionamentos 1-para-1 e então unificá-las. Afinal de contas, quando os dados referentes a um registro de um determinado conceito do domínio da aplicação estão espalhados em várias tabelas com relacionamentos de 1-para-1, isso é um forte indício de que talvez eles deveriam estar numa mesma tabela.

## Onde posso aplicar o conceito de normalização?

O conceito de normalização e as formas normais se aplicam somente aos bancos de dados relacionais. Outros tipos de bancos de dados que não sejam relacionais (por exemplo, uma aplicação que salve dados em arquivos organizados em pastas), também podem ter conceitos análogos a normalização para eliminar-se redundâncias, melhorar-se a estrutura e reduzir-se a possibilidade de produzirem-se anomalias. Porém, nesse campo, os conceitos de normalização não são tão bem definidos quanto no caso de bases de dados relacionais e cada caso terá as suas particularidades.

O caso do NoSQL em especial é bem interessante, pois a ideia dele é modelar dados que não necessitam ter uma forte consistência (o que se denomina consistência eventual), e muitas vezes os seus dados provêm de locais onde não há uma estrutura muito forte e bem definida para os dados. Por esse motivo, não faz tanto sentido falar-se em normalização em bases NoSQL quanto se faz com SQL relacional, pois a ideia do NoSQL é aceitar, tolerar e saber lidar com eventuais anomalias e ser capaz de se virar mesmo se elas surgirem. **Bases de dados NoSQL sacrificam consistência em troca de escalabilidade, e por esse motivo, anomalias têm que ser toleradas.** Apesar disso, ainda assim existem alguns conceitos referentes à normalização em NoSQL, mas não são tão bem definidos ou amadurecidos. Veja um pouco sobre isso [aqui](http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/database-normalization-still-relevant-nosql-world).

Ah, e é importante dizer que se o banco de dados tiver sido mal-concebido para o domínio ao qual se destina, não será a normalização ou a desnormalização que irá salvá-lo. Nada te impede de chegar até a 5FN ou até mesmo na DKNF e ainda assim ter um banco de dados mal-projetado, gambiarrado e/ou inadequado se ele foi mal-idealizado por razões alheias à normalização.

## Normalização de dados e normalização de banco de dados

Para fechar a resposta a esta pergunta, *normalização de banco de dados* consiste na normalização da estrutura do banco de dados, enquanto que *normalização de dados* corresponde à normalização dos dados já existentes nas tabelas.

Entretanto, especialmente em caso de reestruturações de bancos de dados que já estão em produção, os dois conceitos andam tão juntos e misturados que nem acaba fazendo sentido falar-se em um deles sem estar falando também do outro. Daí, em muitas situações que acontecem na prática, eles acabam sendo colocados como se fossem sinônimos.

Comment: Com essa "incompleta", eu já entendi melhor o conceito. Muito obrigado por gastar seu precioso tempo +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que agora minha resposta está pronta. :)

Comment: Só uma dúvida, no exemplo da 1NF, se a tabela tivesse 4 campos de telefone (telefone1, telefone2, ...), resolveria o problema? Não me ficou claro se é uma coluna com múltiplos valores, ou, também, múltiplos colunas "iguais".  No caso de não ser um problema na 1NF, só se tornaria um na 6NF?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Resolveria entre aspas. Isso é uma forma bem tosca, limitada e gambiarrada de se fingir que não é um campo multivalorado, mas serve para driblar/enganar a 1FN. A definição de campo multivalorado é um campo com múltiplos valores e não múltiplos campos para representar múltiplos valores (que eu acho que é ainda pior do que não estar na 1FN, ou no mínimo tão ruim quanto)...

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam ...No caso, você pode até atingir a 6FN mantendo essa gambiarra. Isso que demonstra que normalização por si só não é o suficiente para se criar uma modelagem boa, pois é perfeitamente possível ter-se uma modelagem horrorosa e inadequada e mesmo assim normalizada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ótima resposta +1, porém estou com uma dúvida, talvez idiota, consoante a 2 FN. Esta afirmativa: "Se eu possuir uma chave primária de um único campo, ou seja, não composto, a relação já estará na 2 FN"  está correta? Pois sempre li  em 2FN com chave primária composta, então deduzi a afirmação acima como correta, porém não encontro nenhuma bibliografia afirmando isto, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @LuizAugusto A afirmação é falsa. Basta você ter algo como `id_carro` sendo a chave primária simples e você colocar como demais colunas `placa`, `cor`, `id_proprietario` e `nome_proprietario`. O campo `nome_proprietario` depende de `id_proprietario` e não de `id_carro`, logo isso é uma violação da 2FN.

Answer (score 16):

A pergunta já tem uma resposta muito boa, quase um capítulo de um livro dando todos os detalhes, mas senti falta de algo importante nela que percebo que muita gente confunde ou não entende porque a normalização é necessária, e assim tem uma forma "resumida" para entender o assunto sem precisar ver todas as formas normais.

## *Desnormalização* indevida

Especialmente em tempos de NoSQL (particularmente em modelo de documento) vejo a normalização sendo atacada indevidamente, muitas vezes por pessoas que não a entendem (vou desconsiderar a má fé para tentar dar um motivo para sua tecnologia preferida existir e ser ubíqua, o que NoSQL não é e não deve ser).

Também não estou dizendo que a normalização mesmo sendo adequada deva ser aplicada sempre, só tenha claro que no momento que não aplicar terá o fardo de lidar com isso. Uma regra sendo ignorada com consciência pode ser útil. Um dos problemas do modelo de documento é que ele "exige" a *desnormalização* em "tudo", então a regra passa ser descumprir a regra e a exceção fazer o adequado.

## Canonicidade

Problemas que não exigem normalização não devem ser normalizados, mas o que deve ser, quase sempre deve por um motivo básico, é necessário que uma informação seja [**canônica**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/260464/101), ou seja, ela só deve existir em um lugar da sua base de dados. Não quer dizer que não possa haver repetição, esse é um erro comum. Eu explico isso na pergunta [O DRY é para evitar redundâncias, certo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) que é um conceito mal entendido pela maioria das pessoas achando que o problema é a repetição. O mesmo que vale para o código vale para o dado, é importante ter uma referência única sobre aquele conhecimento.

Toda vez que o mesmo conhecimento é replicado em outro lugar seu código tem que ser responsável por administrar essa réplica. É isto que deseja para seu código, ter que lidar com esse fardo? O que acontece se ele (você) falhar nisso? **Inconsistência**. Você pode ter a mesma informação modificada em um lugar e não no outro, e você tem a mesma informação em dois estados diferentes e dependendo de quem for acessar um ou outro mostrará algo inconsistente.

Note que existem casos que uma mesma informação em determinado momento precisa ser congelada e se torna outra informação, quando isto ocorre não importa a repetição, pelo contrário, deve repetir mesmo, porque essa repetição é circunstancial, em algum momento potencialmente elas serão diferentes e devem ser mesmo, porque elas passaram representar algo diferente.

Só porque os dados sejam os mesmos em dois lugares não quer dizer que seja a mesma informação. Assim como só porque existem dois `José da Silva` que são a mesma pessoa. Ou se dois irmãos gêmeos univitelinos sejam a mesma pessoa. Repetição não é o motivo para normalizar, ser canônico é.

## Falsa premissa

Um erro comum que vejo por aí, e deve ser culpa de professores e livros que ensinaram errado, é dizer que normalização serve para reduzir espaço consumido. Isto é apenas um efeito colateral agradável e sempre desejável, mas não é o motivo para normalizar, o motivo é a canonicidade da informação.

Tampouco é correto dizer que espaço hoje não é problema. Ocupar mais espaço faz você acessar mais o armazenamento de massa (HDD ou SSD) e ter menos dados no armazenamento de performance (RAM), isto é prejudicial para a performance.

Claro que normalizar pode trazer algumas dificuldades de performance em algumas situações também, mas tem que pensar bem se vale a pena trocar a dificuldade de manter os dados e o risco de inconsistência pela performance um pouco melhor.

Curiosamente a *desnormalização* pode ajudar [evitar `JOIN` de leitura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216855/101), mas se usado em exagero pode criar uma espécie de `JOIN` de escrita que é muito pior facilitando criar *deadlocks* e outros fenômenos prejudiciais.

A evolução do hardware (NVRAM) tornará o custo de fazer um `JOIN` irrisório e desprezível. Nada evoluirá para ter que lidar bem com informações não-canônicas.

## Normalização correta

Entenda que não estou discutindo a normalização errada. Hoje em todos os bancos de dados relacionais *mainstream* tem maneiras de usar modelos flexíveis de dados que podem evitar a normalização desnecessária.

É interessante dar uma olhada em [Qual a diferença entre Associação, Agregação e Composição em OOP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/86715/101). Geralmente **casos de composição não devem ser normalizados**, em banco de dados isso é mais fácil e melhor de se fazer por causa da maneira como se acessa dados (a não ser que o acesso seja em tamanho fixo de linha, raro hoje em dia). A agregação é caso claro para a normalização. A associação também seria, mas tem casos que é possível transformá-la em composição para efeitos de banco de dados, então é preciso atentar para isto como otimização (a agregação também pode, mas é mais raro).

Um dos motivos que critico os microsserviços é que destrói-se a normalização em nome de uma arquitetura quase sempre não é necessária. Em vez de ter um sistema com informações canônicas tem-se várias subsistemas cada um com sua informação canônica (possivelmente), mas no todo viola-se o DRY por completo e vira um pesadelo cuidar disso.

Cuidado com a regra pela regra, todas elas podem e devem ser quebradas se for mais importante fazê-lo. Para saber quando quebrar é preciso bastante domínio do que está fazendo. Sem quebrar regras já estará fazendo errado por definição, e só acertará por coincidência. Sempre lembrando:

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

**Você pode tolerar anomalia nos seus dados?** NoSQL prega isto.

Tendo essas coisas de forma mais clara, releia a resposta do Victor Stafusa prestando mais atenção aos detalhes dela. Tinha prestado forte atenção a esta frase?

> A principal finalidade do processo de normalização é eliminar as anomalias de inserção, atualização e exclusão.

## Além das formas normais

Um ponto que a resposta aceita não toca é sobre a normalização não tão evidente. O exemplo mais comum que sempre cito é você ter um cliente e um fornecedor, mas ambas são a mesma entidade, se mudar o endereço tem que mudar em dois lugares diferentes. Ou deveria ter só uma entidade e tratar só a relação de clientela ou fornecimento como algo separado (normalizado ou não) ou então se não quiser normalizar certo (uma forma normal não existente nos livros sobre o assunto) deve garantir que alterando na tabela de cliente altere na tabela de fornecedor. Virtualmente nenhum sistema que eu conheço faz isso certo. Curiosamente é mais fácil fazer isto no modelo de documento, mas porque quase todo mundo que adota esse modelo ainda pensa como no relacional não fazem certo também.

## Aprender modelar e normalizar

Modelar dados é provavelmente a característica mais importante que um desenvolvedor deve ter, e a maioria, mesmo experientes, é bem ruim nisto (eu sou ainda depois de 36 anos fazendo). Tendo isso em mente comece se preparar.

Precisa ter uma enorme capacidade de interpretação de texto, e um texto que sequer existe, e entendimento matemático, especialmente conjuntos, sabe aquilo que viu partindo da 3a. série (na minha época) e que quase ninguém dá bola e que muitos professores nem entendem porque estão ensinando aquilo? Se faltar essas coisas, comece tudo de novo, sem alicerce nada para em pé.

## Exemplos de normalização

Eu já dei vários *reviews* sobre modelagem e normalização. Ler estes exemplos pode ajudar ganhar experiência. Só não tome essas coisas como regra. Tem de outras pessoas também, mas é mais difícil eu achar.

- [O que fazer se cliente pode ser tanto PF quanto PJ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101)
- [Como se modela um papel em orientação a objetos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/326641/101)
- [Normalização de banco de dados em sistema de RH](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/402810/101)
- [Dúvidas sobre modelagem de banco de dados, dualidade de ID's](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/322049/101)
- ["Herança" de tabela é uma prática ruim nesse caso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247875/101)
- [Modelagem de lançamentos usando clientes e fornecedores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154748/101)
- [Normalização de tabela para 2a Forma Normal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/250423/101)
- [Melhor forma para normalização de banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/333552/101)
- ["Herança" de tabela é uma prática ruim nesse caso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247875/101)
- [Modelagem para cadastro de entidades abrangente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123499/101)
- [Melhor maneira de manter dados que dependem de uma condição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/74127/101)
- [Armazenar dados que podem ser consultados fora da própria base de dados, vai contra a 1ª Forma Normal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175673/101)
- [Quantas tabelas serão necessárias no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/322175/101)
- [Banco de dados deve seguir o padrão OO?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83702/101)
- [Database com extra headers](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53518/101)
- [Database modelagem, quando é possível desnormalizar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176667/101)
- [Qual a melhor forma de se construir uma tabela MySQL com itens de receitas? Todos ingredientes em uma linha ou um ingrediente por linha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364717/101)
- [Como gerar registro a cada novo relacionamento entre duas entidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87406/101)
- [Como modelar parcelas quando não se sabe quantas são?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87723/101)
- [É realmente necessário criar uma 3ª tabela auxiliar em relacionamentos N-N?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221018/101)
- [Qual a melhor forma de se fazer comentários em post?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278780/101)
- [Herança e Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80948/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

<sub>Me impressiona esta pergunta ter apenas cerca de 4 mil visualizações até o momento que escrevi esta resposta, o que indica muito porque tem tanta aplicação problemática por aí, as pessoas não estão preocupadas com as coisas certas.</sub>

Comment: [Alternativas para o \(anti-\)padrão Entity-Attribute-Value](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15534/91) acho que é um complemento ou um exemplo em partes da sua resposta.

Comment: "*Um dos motivos que critico os microsserviços é que destrói-se a normalização em nome de uma arquitetura quase sempre não-necessária.*" - Estou muito longe de ser um grande conhecedor de microsserviços, mas até onde sei, só uma arquitetura de microsserviços mal-feita ou mal-planejada estaria realmente destruindo a normalização provavelmente por estar sacrificando a canonicidade. Ou no mínimo isso seria um trade-off onde sacrifica-se normalização para ganhar desempenho, algo análogo a uma desnormalização, e só seria válido se feito de forma consciente e bem-pensada.

Comment: Pode ser, só que então eu nunca vi uma bem feita. Tem um jeito de fazer e manter a normalização, cada ms cuidar de uma tabela, o que seria uma das coisas mais bobas que eu já vi. Quando você faz um ms ele envolve tudo o que ele precisa. Aí em outro ms envolve tudo o que ele precisa de forma isolada, só que algumas das coisas que ele tem já tinha no outro, só não teria se ele dependesse do outro ms pra dar essa informação de forma isolada e o ms fazer a relação, o q já vi alguns fazerem, ou seja os ms juntos viram "bancos de dados". Adoraria saber mais sobre o que pensa disto e quem sabe rever.

Comment: Não sei ao certo, pois não conheço o suficiente sobre o assunto. Mas a ideia de microsserviços é a de dividir o domínio em pequenos pedaços que possam ser gerenciados, evoluídos e reutilizados separadamente. Se isso for feito de forma errada, seja pela falta ou pelo excesso, vai dar errado. Aí acho que o que vale é observar a finalidade de cada microsserviço numa perspectiva top-down, aplicar o YAGNI no BD subjacente e substituir o que seriam algumas das chaves estrangeiras do modelo monolítico por URLs ou códigos externos, o que não deixa de ser o que já ocorre com CPF ou CEP, por exemplo.

Comment: @VictorStafusa também não conheço tanto poque nunca fiz e nunca farei. Ele é usado por dois motivos: dar escala (o SO é um dos 50 maiores sites e não precisa) e cumprir a lei de Conway (</sarcasmo>). Mas aí é que entra o banco de dados. Todo mundo diz que não existe ms se você tiver um DB monolítico, ele só existe se cada ms tiver seu próprio DB. Aí você "normaliza" demais, o que acaba sendo uma desnomalização universal. Cada DB tem que ter tudo o que ele precisa para funcionar porque não pode consultar outros, aí não tem duplicação nele, mas tem no universo todo.

Comment: Ou cada ms é uma tabela e ele responde sobre ela e aí fica bem normalizado, ou seja, o ms se torna uma API para acessar aquela tabela e os resultados são todos montados na aplicação, uma total insanidade. Não que a forma que duplica não aconteça isso. E que é o ms mo problema do NoSQL onde o cara joga toda responsabilidade pra aplicação cuidar de tudo que ele não faz, alias quase todo ms usa NoSQL e de fato faz todo sentido, o ms é que não faz. Eu adoro responsabilidade na aplicação, mas até certo ponto, é para definir *queries*, validar e fazer processamento macro.

Comment: Você citou 2 exemplos de ms naturais. Login costuma ser outro. O problema é fazer um ERP com ms onde quase todas tabelas são relacionadas se fizer 2 ou 3 graus de separação. Tem algumas coisas que são fáceis de fazer ms porque são coisas isoladas, são coisas que funcionam como serviços e são pequenos. Quero ver você falar sobre ms em sistemas inteiros. Isso que você está falando não arquitetura de ms é um microsserviço sendo criado porque ele é um ms natural, é diferente de transformar algo que seria um monólito em ms. Me explica como fazer "certo" em um ERP inteiro.

Comment: @VictorStafusa veja só https://www.eximiaco.tech/pt/2019/08/12/event-carried-state-transfer/ todas descrições que eu vejo que pregam microsserviços falam a mesma coisa (5o. parágrafo com negrito)

Comment: @Maniero Estou tentando redigir uma pergunta aqui no SOpt para esclarecer isso. Mas primeiro, vou coletar o material pertinente, vou ver se até o fim-de-semana concluo ela (ou desisto). Mas também tenho um certo receio em fazê-lo porque perguntas desse nível de profundidade são muito difíceis de serem respondidas com alguma coisa além do que nós já temos.

Comment: Não consegui elaborar aquela pergunta, mas achei um link muito interessante e bem novo (de três dias atrás): https://dzone.com/articles/breaking-the-monolithic-database-in-your-microserv

Comment: @VictorStafusa tudo que se fizer certo dá certo e se fizer errado dá errado, a diferença é que algumas coisas são mais fáceis dar certo e outras mais fáceis dar errado. Pra mim, até que algum me convença do contrário ms é mais fácil dar errado justamente por perder a canonicalidade. A única coisa que esse artigo fala, e obviedade pra quem conhece ms é que você deve usar bounded context, que destrói a canonicalidade da informação, minha maior crítica ao DDD. Em nenhum momento ele mostra que dá pra manter a canonicalidade.Ñ tem como,mas ainda espero que alguém me mostre o contrário.`challenging`

Comment: Existe uma forma realmente de manter a canonicalidade com nanoserviços, você faz o serviço só fazer uma operação de pegar a informação no banco de dados e todo tratamento é feito na aplicação, eu sei que tem gente que faz isso, e é uma das coisas mais idiotas que eu já vi na vida http://wiki.c2.com/?ReinventingTheDatabaseInApplication.

Comment: Maniero você está assumindo que em grandes corporações, em que há dezenas e mais dezenas de sistemas acessando a tabela de cliente, basta a normalização correta que vai estar tudo bem. Não camarada, a teoria é linda, a pratica é outra história. Do que adianta bem normalizado se certamente haverá dezenas de aplicativos "mal" feitos usando os dados de forma duvidosa? O melhor mesmo é desnormalizar e ter problemas locais, eu que não quero ter que tolerar sujeira vinda dos outros.

Comment: @danilo onde especificamente eu estou dizendo isso? Eu procurei e não achei. Em algum lugar eu falo que basta normalizar e todo o resto pode ser mal feito que está tudo bem? Porque eu nem reconheceria essa pessoa. O que eu sei bem e não está dito api é que o banco de dados ser API, como muitos fazem, nunca dá certo. Isso tenho bastante experiência, por isso eu não deixo mais acontecer.

Answer (score 14):

Normalização de dados é um conjunto de regras aplicadas a tabelas de banco de dados relacionais a fim de manter a consistência dos dados, evitar duplicações/redundância e problemas com remoções ou atualizações de registros.

As formas normais são 1FN, 2FN, 3FN, BCNF, 4FN e 5FN. As tabelas geralmente são normalizadas até a terceira forma, a quarta e quinta formas normais tratam de problemas específicos.

Comment: What is 1fn, 2fn, 3fn? hehehe

Comment: @WallaceMaxters 1 Forma Normal, é um processo sequencial, por exemplo uma tabela para estar na 3FN deve estar obrigatóriamente na 2FN que por sua vez deve obedecer a 1FN.

Comment: http://www.luis.blog.br/normalizacao-de-dados-e-as-formas-normais.aspx

Comment: Ah, FN significa Forma Normal? Agora comecei a pegar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-key_normal_form

Comment: Simples e fácil. .

Answer (score 1):

A normalização é importante e deve ser levada até à 3FN, mas por questões de performance tambem poderá ser necessário proceder à desnormalização. Por vezes, depois de fazer o modelo de dados todo bonitinho, faz-se o teste de carga e a base de dados arrrrraaasstaaa-se. Pode ser necessário reverter alguma da normalização ;-)
Bom senso!

Comment: Eu concordo com seu ponto de vista apesar de muita gente ter negativado sua resposta. Banco de dados tem que ser analisado juntamente com o negócio. Não existe uma regra que não pode ser "quebrada".