# Muitas tabelas com poucos dados ou poucas tabelas com muitos dados?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Tenho um banco que receberá muitos dados. Estou em dúvida se é melhor organizar os dados em poucas tabelas com muitos dados ou dividir mais os dados em várias tabelas. Em qual dos casos as consultas serão mais rápidas? Estou usando MySQL.

Comment: Depende da modelagem das informações, acredito que isso já otimize muito.

Comment: depende.. voce vai quebrar uma tabela em várias menores e iguais ou vai remodelar o projeto?

Comment: @J.Guilherme, acho que nenhuma das alternativas se aplicam ao meu caso. Mas enfim, a dúvida em qual dos casos seria mais rápida a busca, independente do projeto, considerando um banco genérico

Comment: Vamos supor que eu ainda vá modelar o banco

Comment: hmmmm... se você já sabe onde procurar, então ter poucos dados é mais rádido, mas isso só começa a fazer diferença na casa das 10^6 registros...  o ideal é que voce tenha o número de tabelas que deixe o sistema normalizado... se a query tiver ficando lenta você pode passar o banco pra cache ou aplicar a arquitetura shard... vou sumarizar isso em uma resposta

Comment: Votei para fechar. Essa pergunta vai levar a muito "eu acho". E na verdade,  tanto faz. Cada caso é um caso, cada caso exigirá uma estrutura diferente. Acho também que a pergunta ficou muito ampla.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Segundo as regras de normalização de banco de dados:

É melhor ter mais tabelas com menos atributos em cada, e fazer associação por chaves estrangeiras.

**1ª Forma Normal:** todos os atributos de uma tabela devem ser atômicos, ou seja, a tabela não deve conter grupos repetidos e nem atributos com mais de um valor. Para deixar nesta forma normal, é preciso identificar a chave primária da tabela, identificar a(s) coluna(s) que tem(êm) dados repetidos e removê-la(s), criar uma nova tabela com a chave primária para armazenar o dado repetido e, por fim, criar uma relação entre a tabela principal e a tabela secundária. Por exemplo, considere a tabela Pessoas a seguir.

```
PESSOAS = {ID+ NOME + ENDERECO + TELEFONES}
```

Ela contém a chave primária ID e o atributo TELEFONES é um atributo multivalorado e, portanto, a tabela não está na 1FN. Para deixá-la na 1FN, vamos criar uma nova tabela chamada TELEFONES que conterá PESSOA_ID como chave estrangeira de PESSOAS e TELEFONE como o valor multivalorado que será armazenado.

```
PESSOAS = { ID + NOME + ENDERECO }
TELEFONES = { PESSOA_ID + TELEFONE }
```

---

**2ª Forma Normal:** antes de mais nada, para estar na 2FN é preciso estar na 1FN. Além disso, todos os atributos não chaves da tabela devem depender unicamente da chave primária (não podendo depender apenas de parte dela). Para deixar na segunda forma normal, é preciso identificar as colunas que não são funcionalmente dependentes da chave primária da tabela e, em seguida, remover essa coluna da tabela principal e criar uma nova tabela com esses dados. Por exemplo, considere a tabela ALUNOS_CURSOS a seguir.

```
ALUNOS_CURSOS = { ID_ALUNO + ID_CURSO + NOTA + DESCRICAO_CURSO }
```

Nessa tabela, o atributo DESCRICAO_CURSO depende apenas da chave primária ID_CURSO. Dessa forma, a tabela não está na 2FN. Para tanto, cria-se uma nova tabela chamada CURSOS que tem como chave primária ID_CURSO e atributo DESCRICAO retirando, assim, o atributo DESCRICAO_CURSO da tabela ALUNOS_CURSOS.

```
ALUNOS_CURSOS = {ID_ALUNO + ID_CURSO + NOTA}
CURSOS = {ID_CURSO + DESCRICAO}
```

---

**3ª Forma Normal:** para estar na 3FN, é preciso estar na 2FN. Além disso, os atributos não chave de uma tabela devem ser mutuamente independentes e dependentes unicamente e exclusivamente da chave primária (um atributo B é funcionalmente dependente de A se, e somente se, para cada valor de A só existe um valor de B). Para atingir essa forma normal, é preciso identificar as colunas que são funcionalmente dependentes das outras colunas não chave e extraí-las para outra tabela. Considere, como exemplo, a tabela FUNCIONARIOS a seguir.

```
FUNCIONARIOS = { ID + NOME + ID_CARGO + DESCRICAO_CARGO }
```

O atributo DESCRICAO_CARGO depende exclusivamente de ID_CARGO (atributo não chave) e, portanto, deve-se criar uma nova tabela com esses atributos. Dessa forma, ficamos com as seguintes tabelas:

```
FUNCIONARIOS = { ID + NOME + ID_CARGO }
CARGOS = { ID_CARGO + DESCRICAO }
```

---

Fonte [dsc](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~pet/jornal/maio2011/materias/recapitulando.html)

Answer (score 2):

Como tudo em TI.. depende!!!

Em um banco de dados relacional ter as informações normalizadas é uma boa opção. Claro que usar índices é fundamental. O pessoal comentou até a terceira forma normal, e concordo com eles... mas é bom saber que temos mais, [seis ao todo e mais alguns detalhes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%C3%A9-normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados)... E cabe a você saber até onde deve ir!

Quando se trata de DML (Data Manipulation Language, ou os INSERT, UPDADE, DELETE e MERGE), isso pode mudar um pouco... Inserir registros em tabelas diferentes em grandes volumes pode ser "demorado" e já vi práticas de ter uma única tabela para input e posteriormente fragmentar esses dados em suas devidas tabelas.

Answer (score 1):

Como você está trabalhando com modelo relacional, eu recomendo fazer o `modelo entidade-relacionamento` seguindo as `três formas normais` e não adicionar mais tabelas do que as que o modelo gerar.

Conforme os dados forem crescendo podem-se aplicar técnicas de escalabilidade.

Uma famosa técnica é passar tabelas do banco de dados em `cache` para deixar as consultas mais rápidas.

Uma outra é usar o conceito de `Sharding` e quebrar uma tabela grande em tabelas menores, distribuindo a carga e também agilizando a busca. Grosseiramente falando, é o conceito de `load balancer` aplicado à banco de dados.