# É possível salvar vários valores em um único campo do banco

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Declarei o campo no banco de dados assim:

```
descricao VARCHAR2(5)not null,
```

É possível, por exemplo, salvar **1**,**2**,**3**,**4** de uma só vez (um único registro) no campo `descricao`, onde cada um desses valores se refere a uma coisa específica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível, se a coluna é `varchar` pode colocar o texto que quiser dentro dela. Mas raramente é o mais correto de se fazer. Pode ser seu caso, não conheço o que pretende. Claro que sua aplicação terá que saber tratá-lo adequadamente sempre.

Se tem 5 valores sempre, crie 5 colunas. Se vai de 0 à 5 valores, pode ser útil fazer o mesmo, mMas pode ser considerado como desperdício, há quem diga que é caso para [normalização de banco de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

Também é possível criar um [`varray`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjcol.htm), mas é um tópico mais avançado.

Pode fazer em C# ou qualquer outra linguagem que tenha capacidade de acessar todos recursos do Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma fácil e simples é utilizar um caractere separador no campo `varchar`. exemplo '|' (pipe) e formatar em SQL na inserção no banco e na consulta.

Mas não acho nem necessário e nem recomendo fazer isso. Recomendo que siga as instruções do amigo *Maniero*