# O que é integridade referencial?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

Já procurei em vários sites e até agora não consegui entender muito bem o que é integridade referencial. Por isso, resolvi perguntar aqui.

Quando usar a integridade referencial?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Integridade referencial é um conceito relacionado à chaves estrangeiras. Este conceito diz que o valor que é chave estrangeira em uma tabela destino, deve ser chave primária de algum registro na tabela origem. Quando essa regra é desrespeitada, então temos o caso em que a integridade referencial é violada.

Vejamos a terminologia: Integridade vem de íntegro, inteiro, completo, correto. Referencial vem de referência, indicar algo ou alguém. Portanto, integridade referencial é indicar algo ou alguém de forma íntegra, completa, correta.

Por exemplo, veja essas duas tabelas:

```
Carros
Placa (PK) | Modelo | Proprietário (FK)
-----------+--------+------------------
ABC-1233   | Passat | 1
DEF-4566   | Fiesta | 2
UUV-7890   | Palio  | 1

Proprietários
ID (PK) | Nome
--------+------
1       | Pedro
2       | Maria
```

Estas tabelas têm integridade referencial, pois os carros que têm proprietário com ID 1, podem ser encontrados na tabela de proprietários como sendo do Pedro. O carro de proprietário com ID 2 pode ser encontrado como sendo da Maria.

Agora, imagine que nós venhamos inserir um carro de placa EJB-6520, do modelo Celta e do proprietário com o ID 3. Ocorre que não há nenhum proprietário de ID 3. Se o banco de dados permitir essa inclusão, ocorrerá uma violação da integridade referencial, pois estará sendo feita uma referência a uma entidade inexistente. O mesmo ocorreria se quisermos alterar o proprietário de um dos carros colocando o ID do proprietário como 3.

Por outro lado, se nós quisermos deletar a Maria do banco de dados sem deletar o carro de placa DEF-4566 e nem alterá-lo, novamente teremos uma violação da integridade referencial, pois se o banco de dados permitir que essa exclusão seja feita, a integridade referencial será violada ao termos um carro que tem como dono, uma entidade agora inexistente.

A maioria dos bancos de dados relacionais modernos existentes impõem integridade referencial quando você tenta inserir, alterar ou excluir entidades no qual há chaves estrangeiras envolvidas. Entretanto, o MySQL quando utilizado com engine MyISAM é uma notável exceção (o recomendável é utilizar InnoDB nesses casos). Também é possível que as tabelas tenham sido modeladas sem que a chave estrangeira tenha sido explicitamente modelada no banco de dados e fique apenas implícita no nível da aplicação, e portanto o banco de dados não terá como verificar a integridade nesse caso.

Se uma violação de integridade ocorrer, o seu banco de dados apresentará registros inconsistentes que apontam para entidades que não existem, o que tende a se manifestar nas aplicações sob a forma de vários tipos de problemas.

Comment: Estou fazendo um sistema para videolocadora e se algum funcionário quiser deletar os filmes de uma locação feita por cliente ou deletar algum cliente de uma locação que não foi devolvida, pode ocorrer problemas  no meu sistema?

Comment: @IgorContini Sim pode, isso daria problema com certeza. Se o banco de dados deixar isso acontecer, o seu sistema vai ficar maluco com informações corrompidas. A solução neste caso é avisar o funcionário que a exclusão do cliente não pode ser feita porque ele tem filmes alugados. Se a exclusão for necessária, primeiro deve-se desassociar os filmes locados (via devolução, marcar como perdido ou algo semelhante) e só depois deve-se excluir o cliente. Há muitos sistemas por aí que tem comportamento semelhante: você não pode excluir alguma coisa enquanto houver outras coisas ligadas nela.

Comment: Entendi muito bem e vou seguir o que falou! Muito obrigado!