# Problema ao realizar join em tabelas com generalização

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estou com dificuldades de realizar um JOIN em tabelas o problema é o seguinte:

Em um sistema de boletim escolar possuo usuários, dentre eles alunos, responsáveis e colaboradores da escola. Preciso gerar um comando SQL que ao informar o CPF do(s) responsável(is), ele liste todos os alunos relacionados ao CPF desse(s) responsável(is).

Segue o modelo:

[image: Modelo]

Esta é a melhor forma de implementar essa "Generalização" e esse relacionamento entre os responsáveis e os alunos, já que todos são usuários? Alguém pode me ajudar?

Código SQL:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`tipo_usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`tipo_usuario` (
  `idtipo_usuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `funcao` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtipo_usuario`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`usuario` (
  `idusuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `data_nasc` DATE NULL,
  `telefone` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `celular` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`, `tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`),
  INDEX `fk_usuario_tipo_usuario_idx` (`tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_tipo_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`tipo_usuario` (`idtipo_usuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`aluno`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`aluno` (
  `idaluno` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario_idusuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idaluno`, `usuario_idusuario`, `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`),
  INDEX `fk_aluno_usuario1_idx` (`usuario_idusuario` ASC, `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_idusuario` , `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`usuario` (`idusuario` , `tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`responsavel`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`responsavel` (
  `idresponsavel` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usuario_idusuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idresponsavel`, `usuario_idusuario`, `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`),
  INDEX `fk_responsavel_usuario1_idx` (`usuario_idusuario` ASC, `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_responsavel_usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_idusuario` , `usuario_tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`usuario` (`idusuario` , `tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`aluno_has_responsavel`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`aluno_has_responsavel` (
  `aluno_idaluno` INT NOT NULL,
  `aluno_usuario_idusuario` INT NOT NULL,
  `responsavel_idresponsavel` INT NOT NULL,
  `responsavel_usuario_idusuario` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aluno_idaluno`, `aluno_usuario_idusuario`, `responsavel_idresponsavel`, `responsavel_usuario_idusuario`),
  INDEX `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_responsavel1_idx` (`responsavel_idresponsavel` ASC, `responsavel_usuario_idusuario` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_aluno1_idx` (`aluno_idaluno` ASC, `aluno_usuario_idusuario` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_aluno1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`aluno_idaluno` , `aluno_usuario_idusuario`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`aluno` (`idaluno` , `usuario_idusuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_responsavel1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`responsavel_idresponsavel` , `responsavel_usuario_idusuario`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`responsavel` (`idresponsavel` , `usuario_idusuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Eu não faria relacionado ao CPF. Como o perfil de usuário pode ter várias atribuições e privilégios em várias telas do programa. Pode ser desejado que em determinado momento, você como gerente do sistema, se logue como usuário para ver se tudo corre como imaginou. Portanto vincularia isso ao perfil da pessoa que esta logando e não ao CPF dela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um relacionamento de generalização pode ser modelado de várias maneiras. A maneira que acho que te servirá melhor é a seguinte:

- A tabela mais genérica tem alguma chave primária.
- As tabelas mais específicas tem a mesma chave primária da tabela mais genérica.
- A chave primária das tabelas mais específicas são também chaves estrangeiras da tabela mais genérica.

Além disso, se a sua tabela tem um campo `AUTO_INCREMENT` então esse campo é suficiente para ser a chave primária. Ou seja, nesse caso você não precisa ter mais campos na chave primária além do que está marcado como `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Isso também simplificará as chaves estrangeiras que forem exportadas a partir dessa tabela e os índices utilizados.

Nunca use `ON DELETE NO ACTION` ou `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`. Isso irá acabar com a sua [integridade referencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166120/132). Ainda mais que você está usando o InnoDB que foi concebido com a ideia de respeitar-se a integridade referencial (coisa que o MyIsam não faz).

Eis como ficaria o seu código SQL pensando-se no que explanei acima:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`tipo_usuario` (
  `id_tipo_usuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `funcao` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_tipo_usuario`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`usuario` (
  `id_usuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `data_nasc` DATE NULL,
  `telefone` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `celular` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `id_tipo_usuario` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`),
  INDEX `fk_usuario_tipo_usuario_idx` (`tipo_usuario_idtipo_usuario` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_tipo_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_usuario`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`aluno` (
  `id_aluno` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_aluno`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_aluno`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`usuario` (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`responsavel` (
  `id_responsavel` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_responsavel`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_responsavel_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_responsavel`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`usuario` (`id_usuario`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`aluno_has_responsavel` (
  `id_aluno` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_responsavel` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_aluno`, `id_responsavel`),
  INDEX `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_responsavel_idx` (`id_responsavel` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_aluno_idx` (`id_aluno` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_aluno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_aluno`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`aluno` (`id_aluno`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_aluno_has_responsavel_responsavel`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_responsavel`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`responsavel` (`id_responsavel`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Observe que as chaves estrangeiras exportadas ficaram muito mais simples e os índices também ficarão muito mais simples. Índices que correspondem a chave primária são desnecessários, uma vez que o banco de dados já os criará implicitamente.

Além disso, você realmente não precisa disso que está abaixo, mesmo tendo sido gerado automaticamente. Por isso retirei:

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Por fim, sua consulta SQL ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ua.*
FROM usuario ua
INNER JOIN aluno a ON ua.id_usuario = a.id_aluno
INNER JOIN aluno_has_responsavel h ON a.id_aluno = h.id_aluno
INNER JOIN responsavel r ON h.id_responsavel = r.id_responsavel
INNER JOIN usuario ur ON ur.id_usuario = r.id_responsavel
WHERE ur.cpf = '12345678910';
```

Ah, e não sei se você realmente precisa da tabela `tipo_usuario`. Se a ideia dela é saber se um usuário é aluno, colaborador ou responsável, então ela é desnecessária. Para isso, basta ver em qual das tabelas ela aparece.

Comment: `SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;` isso é gerado pelo MySQL Workbench. Ele faz isso pra desabilitar a verificação de FKs durante a execução do script e depois reabilita (para evitar erros na criação das tabelas).

Comment: @KaduAmaral Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: @VictorStafusa a consulta que você passou não funciona pois o CPF do responsável está na tabela usuários e não na de responsável então retorna o erro 'Unknown column 'r.cpf' in 'where clause'.

Comment: Não estou conseguindojustamente pegar o nome do aluno e  ID dele através do CPF do usuário responsável por ele. Com essa consulta consigo trazer todos os registros vinculados mas não pelo CPF:

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
  a.id_aluno,
  u.nome
FROM usuario u, aluno a
  INNER JOIN aluno_has_responsavel h ON a.id_aluno = h.id_aluno
  INNER JOIN responsavel r ON r.id_responsavel = h.id_responsavel
WHERE h.id_aluno = u.id_usuario AND u.id_tipo_usuario = h.id_responsavel

Comment: @TiagoGóes Desculpe-me. Corrigi a SQL. Diga-me se agora está certo. Observe que a tabela usuário aparece duas vezes na consulta, uma como sendo o aluno e outra como sendo o responsável.

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade o que você precisa necessita de um número menor de campos, tabelas e consequentemente relacionamentos:

[image: Modelo de exemplo]

O select de busca ficaria algo como:

```
SELECT
    A.*
FROM Responsavel R
INNER JOIN Usuario U ON R.idUsuario = U.idUsuario
INNER JOIN Aluno A ON A.idResponsavel = R.idResponsavel
WHERE
    R.cpf = '99.999.999-99'
```

Comment: Gostei da sua resposta, +1. Entretanto aqui você está presumindo que o relacionamento entre aluno e responsável possa ser 1-para-N. Ou seja, no seu modelo há apenas um responsável para cada aluno (mas um mesmo responsável pode o ser para vários alunos), sendo que no original, isso era N-para-N.

Comment: Eu ainda removeria a entidade `responsavel` e a entidade `aluno` seria uma relacional entre `aluno.idAluno(usuario.id) x aluno.idResponsavel(usuario.id)`

Comment: Concordo @VictorStafusa. Obrigado pelo complemento da resposta.

Comment: Quanto a remoção da entidade "responsavel" e "aluno", não recomendo @KaduAmaral, tendo em vista que elas podem conter dados específicos para responsáveis e alunos (como matrícula, etc..)

Comment: Sim no caso de terem dados específicos para cada até concordo que devam existir essas entidades, mas nesses casos acredito que a generalização apenas atrapalharia olhando do ponto de vista de desenvolvimento, visto que pra dar manutenção no responsável você teria que trabalhar com duas entidades distintas.

Comment: Também concordo. Aí entramos em outra seara: implementar as entidades `responsavel` e `aluno` no início do projeto prevendo que "talvez" possam conter mais dados, ou somente quando for necessário (o que pode gerar outra série de problemas de testes, erros e alterações de código e banco de dados). Aí já é um problema de projeto.