# Como fazer select auto relacionamento N:N

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Pessoal não estou conseguindo realizar uma consulta SQL com relacionamento N:N. Tenho uma tabela de usuários e outra com auto relacionamento usuario_has_usuario, que serão cadastrados responsáveis e alunos (de uma escola) gostaria de listar os alunos pelo CPF do(s) usuário(os) tipo responsável.

Modelo: [image: Modelo]

A consulta que estou utilizando lista todos os alunos, mas não estou conseguindo atrelar para trazer os alunos pelo CPF dos responsáveis

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  u.idusuario,
  u.nome
from usuario u
INNER JOIN usuario_has_usuario uu ON u.idusuario = uu.aluno
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

SQL do banco:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`tipo_user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`tipo_user` (
  `idtipo_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `funcao` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtipo_user`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`usuario` (
  `idusuario` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `data_nasc` DATE NULL,
  `telefone` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `celular` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `tipo_user_idtipo_user` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuario`, `tipo_user_idtipo_user`),
  INDEX `fk_usuario_tipo_user_idx` (`tipo_user_idtipo_user` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_tipo_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tipo_user_idtipo_user`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`tipo_user` (`idtipo_user`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `testeboletim`.`usuario_has_usuario`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testeboletim`.`usuario_has_usuario` (
  `responsavel` INT NOT NULL,
  `aluno` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`responsavel`, `aluno`),
  INDEX `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario2_idx` (`aluno` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario1_idx` (`responsavel` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`responsavel`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`usuario` (`idusuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuario_has_usuario_usuario2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`aluno`)
    REFERENCES `testeboletim`.`usuario` (`idusuario`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Pergunta relacionada (não é duplicata): [Problema ao realizar join em tabelas com generalização](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173163/132)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O SQL é assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM usuario a
INNER JOIN usuario_has_usuario h ON a.idusuario = h.aluno
INNER JOIN usuario r ON r.idusuario = h.responsavel
WHERE r.cpf = '12345678910';
```

Para outras informações, ver a [minha outra resposta na pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173207/132).

Observe que começamos na tabela `usuario` com o aluno, navegamos (usando o `INNER JOIN`) para o relacionamento na `usuario_has_usuario` e então, navegamos de novo (mais uma vez, com o `INNER JOIN`) para a tabela `usuario`, mas desta vez usando o outro relacionamento.

Comment: Obrigado @Victor certinho !