# Armazenar dados que podem ser consultados fora da própria base de dados, vai contra a 1ª Forma Normal?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, engenharia-de-software, normalização

Por exemplo, tenho uma fatura, que posso consultar em uma outra base de dados (mas não de minha propriedade), um exemplo seria o PagSeguro. Armazeno somente o número de identificação da fatura para poder consultar.

Ai vem a dúvida, armazenar esses dados que podem ser consultados entraria em conflito com a **normalização de bancos de dados**, mais especificamente, com a 1FN - 1ª Forma Normal?

Comment: No lugar de guardar só `numero de identificação` vc quer saber se guardar todas as outras informações vai violar a 1FN?

Comment: Isso mesmo, se armazenar esses dados que podem ser consultados, violaria...

Comment: Tópico relevante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/132

Comment: Imagino que quer guardar tudo para o caso de uma indisponibilidade, não vejo isso violando a 1FN. Uma violação pode ocorrer por dois motivos colunas com informação duplicada ex: uma tabela com 2 ou mais campos para telefones ou emails e ter campos multivalorados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Armazenar em uma tabela separada na sua base de dados não violaria a primeira forma normal. Essa normalização não impõe nada que a informação deva estar em algum lugar externo, ela se refere ao modelo relacional da sua base de dados. Armazenar na mesma tabela será uma violação.

A questão é saber se o resultado será o esperado. Os dados no recurso externo podem mudar? O que acontece se isso ocorrer? Você quer que os dados na sua base de dados sejam atualizados também, ou o ideal é que permaneçam como estavam no momento do uso? Se for a última opção, como resolve se a informação externa for usada mais uma vez estiver diferente? Duvido que seja o caso de uma fatura, mas sei lá como eles operam.

Independente da resposta, faça o que precisa fazer. Não fique preocupado se está na forma normal ou não. É bom que esteja, mas se tiver motivos para não seguir a forma normal, não siga, ela não é obrigatória. Se começar fazer porque alguém disse que sempre deve fazer assim, estará fazendo errado. Faça o que é adequado para seu projeto. [Desnormalizar é interessante também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22069/101).

Não conheço o caso concreto em detalhes, mas provavelmente eu traria os dados para minha base para não ficar dependendo de recursos externos. Dependendo do caso pode existir a necessidade de um mecanismo de verificação se os dados estão atualizados.

Comment: Também penso dessa forma, de querer armazenar na própria dada base para não precisar depender de recursos externos. E sobre a mudança de dados do recurso externo, a única informação que pode mudar, é o  status de pagamento, que no caso já armazeno a cada mudança (recebendo uma notificação por POST do PagSeguro)

Answer (score 3):

**Não.** A primeira forma normal dita que você não pode ter colunas multivaloradas, e não é isso o que você está tendo. Tópico relevante para maiores esclarecimentos: [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/132)

Uma vez que você armazena o número da fatura a ser consultado, isso é o análogo a uma chave estrangeira. Isso não constitui (ao menos não por si só) nenhuma violação de alguma forma normal, muito menos a primeira forma normal. Apesar disso, ainda é possível que você possa estar violando alguma forma normal dependendo de onde ou como você armazena isso.

Além disso, o conceito de normalização se aplica a base de dados relacionais. O seu caso **não é** uma base de dados relacional, ao menos não puramente, e sim uma base distribuída por serviços web. Assim sendo, você não pode inventar uma consulta SQL que faça *joins* incluindo dados de tabelas da sua fatura, porque o webservice do PagSeguro não funciona assim, e uma outra abordagem seria necessária. Além disso, uma vez que os dados são mantidos em lugares distintos e controlados por entes distintos, não há garantias prontas de haver [integridade referencial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166120/132).