# Como pegar valor de uma coluna do Banco de Dados usando C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

Tenho uma aplicação web que usa essas 3 tabelas:

**Cliente:**

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTE(
ID_CLIENTE INT PRIMARY KEY,
CLIENTE VARCHAR(50),
ENDERECO VARCHAR(50),
CIDADE VARCHAR(30),
CEP VARCHAR(9),
UF CHAR(2)
);
```

**Pedido:**

```
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO (
NUM_PEDIDO INT PRIMARY KEY,
ID_CLIENTE INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID_CLIENTE),
ID_VENDEDOR INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES VENDEDOR(ID_VENDEDOR),
PRAZO_ENTREGA VARCHAR (50)
);
```

**Item_Pedido:**

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_PEDIDO(
ID_ITEM_PEDIDO INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
NUM_PEDIDO INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PEDIDO(NUM_PEDIDO),
ID_PRODUTO INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUTO(ID_PRODUTO),
QUANTIDADE INT
);
```

Por causa da [Integridade Referêncial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166120/o-que-%C3%A9-integridade-referencial), sempre que eu for excluir um cliente, devo excluir não só os pedidos feitos por ele, mas também os itens desse pedido.
Mas, como visto no código acima, a tabela **ITEM_PEDIDO** não tem o relacionamento com **Cliente**, sendo assim necessário primeiro identificar todos os registros que estão relacionados com o pedido desse cliente. Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como pegar a chave primária desse pedido, armazenando ela dentro de um `int` e depois, usando como parâmetro  para a exclusão dos itens do pedido ?

Um exemplo do meu objetivo:

```
Cliente c = new Cliente();
c.ID_Cliente = 1;
int PK = "select PEDIDO.NUM_PEDIDO where ID_Cliente = "+c.ID_Cliente;
SqlDataSource1.DeleteCommand = "delete from ITEM_PEDIDO where NUM_PEDIDO = "+PK;
SqlDataSource1.Delete();
```

Comment: Você quer fazer isso utilizando SQL mesmo, como na resposta abaixo, ou fazer isso direto do C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis uma forma de solucionar que envolve apagar primeiro as linhas da tabela ITEM_PEDIDO, a seguir da tabela PEDIDO para finalmente excluir o cliente da tabela CLIENTE.

```
-- código #1
-- cliente a apagar da tabela de clientes
declare @excCliente int;
set @excCliente= ...;


BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE ITEM_PEDIDO
  where NUM_PEDIDO in (SELECT NUM_PEDIDO
                         from PEDIDO
                         where ID_CLIENTE = @excCliente);

DELETE PEDIDO
  where ID_CLIENTE = @excCliente;

DELETE CLIENTE
  where ID_CLIENTE = @excCliente;

COMMIT;
```

Para manter a consistência do banco de dados, tudo envolvido pelo par BEGIN TRANSACTION / COMMIT.

A variável @excCliente deve ser assinalada com a identificação do cliente a ser excluído.

---

Outra forma é declarar as colunas ID_CLIENTE (tabela PEDIDO) e NUM_PEDIDO (tabela ITEM_PEDIDO) com a ação `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

```
-- código #2
tabela PEDIDO
...
ID_CLIENTE INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID_CLIENTE)
            ON DELETE CASCADE,
...

tabela ITEM_PEDIDO
...
NUM_PEDIDO INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PEDIDO(NUM_PEDIDO)
                         ON DELETE CASCADE,
...
```

Dessa forma, ao apagar uma linha da tabela CLIENTE, automaticamente todos os pedidos (e respectivos itens do pedido) do cliente são apagados.

```
-- código #3
-- cliente a apagar da tabela de clientes
declare @excCliente int;
set @excCliente= ...;

  DELETE CLIENTE
  where ID_CLIENTE = @excCliente;
```

Answer (score 1):

De maneira simples, primeiro você precisa pegar todos os pedidos do cliente, e depois apagar. Como são mais de um pedido, joga isso em um SqlDataReader e vai lendo os valores:

```
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select PEDIDO.NUM_PEDIDO where ID_Cliente = @cliente",
      connection);

    connection.Open();

    command.Parameters.Add("@cliente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c.ID_Cliente;

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("delete from ITEM_PEDIDO where NUM_PEDIDO = @pedido",
                connection);

            command2.Parameters.Add("@pedido", SqlDbType.Int).Value = reader.GetInt32(0);

            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
    }
    reader.Close();

    SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("delete from cliente where ID_Cliente = @cliente",
              connection);

    connection.Open();

    command3.Parameters.Add("@cliente", SqlDbType.Int).Value = c.ID_Cliente;

    command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```