# trigger que seta valor default para um campo

Tags: sql, oracle, trigger

segue o enunciado:

> Caso o código do departamento do empregado não seja informado no
>   insert ou caso ele não exista na tabela , atribuir a ele o valor
>   padrão 20;

E fiz o seguinte código:

```
create or replace trigger checar_cod_dept after insert or update of DPT_ID 
    on EMPREGADOS for each row when (DPT_ID not in (select ID from DEPARAMENTO))
begin 
     :new.id := 20;
end;
```

tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPREGADOS (
    NOME VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    SALARIO number(2),
    DPT_ID NUMBER,

    CONSTRAINT DPT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (DPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(ID)  
);

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO (
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOME VARCHAR2(50)    
);
```

Com o código que tentei utilizar, da erro pois não pode usar subqueries... Não consegui pensar em outro jeito.

Obrigado

Comment: Olá viva, numa primeira análise eu diria que não precisas de triggers o "default on null 20" no create table ou alter table, resolviria o problema, adicionalmente pode ser necessário utilizar "CONSTRAINT DPT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (DPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(ID) **ENABLE NOVALIDATE**;" para não validar a constraints se existir dados e fizeres um alter table.

Comment: Então, acredito que meu professor pediu esse exercicio com trigger apenas para fins didaticos

Comment: Ele pediu mesmo com trigger? Na verdade, o uso de triggers numa base de dados deve ser evitado (por exemplo, por perda de performance), e como já constataste existem outras limitações. Quanto ao exercicio e qual a ideia penso que seria para ver a solução apresentada, o que me parece é algo tão simples como um default, valida se resolve, contudo existe algo que tens de garantir, o ID 20 terá sempre de existir na tabela DEPARTAMENTO, isso pode ser gerado no momento de criar a base de dados ao executar um SEED de dados default, aí injetas esse valor sempre.

Comment: Ao garantir o ID 20 na tabela DEPARTAMENTO estás a garantir a integridade refencial da base de dados ER. Tens [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166120/o-que-é-integridade-referencial) mais detalhe sobre isso.

Comment: create or replace trigger checar_cod_dept after insert or update of DPT_ID 
    on EMPREGADOS for each row 
begin 
    If :new.dpt_id is null then :new.dpt_id := 20; end if;
end;

Comment: Não deveria ser BEFORE insert ou update?

Comment: Sim , before claro !

Answer (score 0):

Validei com o SQLFiddle, não tenho Oracle na minha máquina. Sendo inserido o registo sem a coluna DPT_ID define o default 20.

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO (
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    NOME VARCHAR2(50)    
);


CREATE TABLE EMPREGADOS (
    NOME VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    SALARIO number(2),
    DPT_ID NUMBER DEFAULT 20,

    CONSTRAINT DPT_ID_FK FOREIGN KEY (DPT_ID) REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO(ID)
);


INSERT INTO DEPARTAMENTO
(ID, NOME )
VALUES
(20, 'NOME departamento' );

INSERT INTO EMPREGADOS
(NOME, SALARIO )
VALUES
('NOME empregado', 10 );
```