# Dividir tabela em duas?

Tags: banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, modelagem

Tenho uma tabela com 25 colunas (contando as FK) e dois grupos de usuários, um vai acessar somente 10 colunas e o outro vai acessar quase todas. Por achar que tinha muitas colunas em uma única tabela (e pensar em orientação à objeto também) acabei dividindo em duas, mas acho que isso só aumentou a complexidade.

Então gostaria de saber:

**-** 25 colunas é muito para uma tabela?

**-** Pensando em orientação à objetivos, são muitos atributos para uma classe? (Large Class?)

**-** 6 FK é um número alto?

**-** O que seria ideal numa situação como essa?

Colunas:

```
codigo_projeto
codigo_interno
valor *
nota_fiscal *
data_entrega_relatorio
status
observacao1
observacao2
finalidade
tipo
setor
data_instalacao
data_ultima_avaliacao
data_conclusao
data_conclusao_laudo
concluido
idlocalizacao
idcultura
idalvo
idagrotoxico
```

Poderá ser acrescentado mais alguns campos.

Comment: Depende, depende de vários fatores. perincipalmente do seu negocio.

Comment: Não divida tabelas aleatoriamente apenas por dividir, de qualquer jeito. Existem formas corretas e formas erradas de se fazer isso. Com essa quantidade de campos, o provável é que haja algumas normalizações a se fazer. Veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151394/132

Comment: Ah, e se quiser uma melhor ajuda, detalhe quais são os seus 25 campos, um por um. Detalhe quais são as suas 6 FKs e diga quais são os exatos 10 campos devem estar abertos para o primeiro usuário. Sem dar essas informações, o melhor que você vai conseguir é uma resposta vaga, genérica e superficial. Com essas informações, vai ficar bem mais fácil de te dar a resposta que você precisa.

Comment: Eu pensei numa forma genérica pra ter uma noção, mas realmente, sem detalhar fica difícil. Acrescentei as colunas e vendo agora, são menos colunas e FKs do que eu pensei, e também são somente as duas colunas com asterisco que não serão visualizadas por um dos grupos. Observando agora fica evidente que o melhor é não separar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - 25 colunas é muito para uma tabela?

Não, é uma miséria (ainda que a maioria dos modelos sejam até menores que isso).

> - Pensando em orientação à objetivos, são muitos atributos para uma classe? (Large Class?)

Pense na necessidade do seu modelo, esqueça essa coisa de tamanho. Orientação a objeto é outra coisa. Se não entende o que é, nem corra atrás disso. Se acha que te ajudará, entenda completamente como funciona antes de fazer alguma coisa, senão vá no óbvio e ululante.

> - 6 FK é um número alto?

Não, números não importam, o que importa é se está expressando o que precisa. Talvez seja exagerado, mas não por causa do número, só porque pode estar fazendo o que não precisa.

> - O que seria ideal numa situação como essa?

Não dá para saber sem conhecer o problema em profundidade.

Comment: Acrescentei as colunas e são menos campos e FKs do que eu tinha pensado, e são somente dois campos (com asteriscos) que serão exclusivos para um grupo. Bom, está claro que o melhor é não separar. É muito bom saber sobre os números, esse tipo de coisa sempre me deixou em dúvida. Obrigado.