# Melhor performance MySql (uma tabela ou várias tabelas)

Tags: mysql

O que tem melhor performance (ou qual a melhor forma de fazer) em uma banco de dados MySql, várias tabelas, por exemplo 'compras_cliente_01, compras_cliente_02' ou uma tabela 'compras_clientes' com o ID do cliente ?

Exemplo:

Tenho sistema onde poderei cadastrar um cliente, e cadastrar compras feitas por esse cliente. Não existe cadastro de produto, apenas cliente(nome, cpf, email...), e compras(produto, quantidade, valor...).

Minha dúvida é se eu crio uma tabela 'compras' para cada cliente exemplo 'compras_01' para o cliente com ID 01, ou se crio uma tabela 'compras' e coloco uma coluna 'ID_CLIENTE'.

Normalmente eu eu faria da segunda maneira criando uma tabela 'compras' com a coluna 'ID_CLIENTE', mas surgiu o dúvida se as consultas serão mais rápidas se eu fizer utilizando uma tabela para todas as compras ou uma tabela de compras por cliente.

Ps.: Não terá muitos clientes, mas sim muitas compras.

Comment: É uma pergunta simples, não precisa de mais detalhes, se precisar use os comentários que eu respondo, apenas deixar -1 sem acrescentar nada não ajuda.

Comment: Augusto, tudo ira depende do que ira fazer com os dados. Contextualize seu problema. P.S.: Não dei `-1` ;)

Comment: @David, obrigado. Coloquei um exemplo mais claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**  Uma tabela.

---

Se não tivesse contextualizado, a **resposta seria que não teria diferença**, pois se esquecer da regra de negocio a ser aplicada, e entender somente o armazenamento de dados, os dois casos resolveria o problema, e a performance se permaneceria. Com base no primeiro caso, e desconsiderando o fato de poder existir milhares de tabelas de compras, e supor teria um jeito bem engenhoso de colheres os dados, funcionaria. O problema é que não é habitual fazer isso Augusto. Temos algumas regras que ajudam a resolver esse problema e garantir um armazenamento consistente. Sugiro a leitura sobre Normalização de Dados:

> **Normalização dos dados**   A normalização do banco de dados é o processo de transformações na estrutura de um banco de dados que visa
>   a eliminar redundâncias e a eliminar anomalias de inserção,
>   atualização e exclusão.  <sub>Fonte: [O que é normalização de banco de
>   dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%C3%A9-normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados)</sub>

Comment: Você teria que fazer dezenas ou ate mesmo, milhares de `joins` para trazer os dados, por exemplo, se tivesse que fazer um relatório.

Comment: Esse não seria uma problema, no meu caso, pois os dados para relatórios ficariam em outra `database` justamente para não consumir memória dessa outra que terá um fluxo grande de dados.

Comment: Então vou manter uma tabela apenas, se no final vai dar o mesmo resultado na busca dos dados. Obrigado!

Comment: Augusto, recomendo a leitura ainda, dessa artigo, [Melhorando a performance de consultas no SQL-Server](http://b.erickmendonca.com.br/post/48801937309/melhorando-a-performance-de-consultas-no-sql), apesar de ser SQLServer a maioria das regras server para o padrão ANSI