# GROUP BY - Exibir resultado agrupado usando WHERE como condição na mesma tabela - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-select, group-by

Estou tentando montar uma query para buscar resultados em uma tabela onde preciso determinar uma condição para uma coluna, agrupar por outra e Exibir uma terceira.

O banco de dados é composto por 6 Tabelas, 5 delas são consultadas individualmente, contendo: `id`, `entrada`, `saida`, `status`, `materia`, `exibir_entrada`, `exibir_saida`, `compartilhada`.

Abaixo está a imagem da estrutura base das tabelas:

[image: Tabela exemplo da sala de aula]

Até agora, consigo uma consulta agrupando pela matéria. Fiz a query assim:

```php
$QueryBuscarAgruparMaterias = "SELECT count(*),materia FROM $NomeSala GROUP BY materia HAVING materia = 'Geografia'";
$ExeQrBuscarAgruparMaterias = mysql_query($QueryBuscarAgruparMaterias);
  while ($MateriasAgrupadas = mysql_fetch_assoc($ExeQrBuscarAgruparMaterias)){
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $MateriasAgrupadas['entrada'] ?>">
    <?php echo $MateriasAgrupadas['entrada'] ?>
    </option>
  <?php
}
```

Porém o resultado não apresenta a informação que preciso:

[image: Resultado após a query]

Tentei até mesmo fazer um SELECT COMPOSTO:

```sql
select entrada, count(materia) from 
(
    select*from
    (
        select * from $NomeSala WHERE compartilhada = 1 AND materia = 'Geografia'
    )
)as t GROUP BY materia;
```

Mesmo assim, não consigo fazer exibir os registro da coluna `entrada`.

Os dados dessa consulta, vão ser usados para inserir um novo registro em outra tabela, gerando assim uma agenda de aulas, tanto compartilhadas quanto particulares.

Os demais valores serão armazenados em uma tabela com os agendamentos do dia conforme na imagem tem a tabela `03_01_2017`. É nela que preciso inserir as informações.

Comment: O que significa as colunas `status` e `compartilhada`? Quais são os valores válidos dessas colunas? Eles dizem respeito à matéria, a sala, ao horário da sala em questão, ou a alguma outra coisa?

Comment: No _Status_, 0 = livre | 1 = ocupada (Fazer Filtro para inserir novos agendamentos). Em _compartilhada_, 0 = Não Compartilhada | Compartilhada (Exibir caso Compartilhada do horário = 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, criar uma tabela por sala é bobagem. Pense bem, você poderia adicionar uma coluna contendo o número da sala e com isso bastaria uma só tabela.

Além disso, a coluna `exibir_entrada` e a coluna `entrada` contém a mesma informação, apenas exibida de uma forma diferente. Portanto apenas uma delas é necessária. O mesmo pode ser dito para as colunas `exibir_saida` e `saida`. Além disso, a saída é sempre meia hora a mais do que a entrada, então podemos eliminar também.

O `status` também é dispensável, pois basta ver se há alguma disciplina alocada no horário.

Assim sendo, você chegaria em uma tabela contendo: `id`, `id_sala`, `entrada`, `materia`, `compartilhada`.

Entretanto, o seu modelo não está normalizado. Parte da sua dificuldade deve estar advindo disso, pois há bastante dados redundantes e duplicados. Veja mais sobre normalização [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/132). As informações de disciplina e sala devem estar em tabelas separadas. Suspeito fortemente que há outras normalizações que poderiam ser aplicadas, mas teria que ver mais a fundo o que você está tentando fazer.

Além disso, podemos perceber que para cada sala, deve haver uma e apenas uma tupla para cada horário. Assim sendo, podemos transformar o conjunto (`id_sala`, `entrada`) em sua chave primária.

Vamos reestruturar o seu banco de dados da seguinte forma:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sala (
    id_sala int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_sala)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE disciplina (
    nome_disciplina VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (nome_disciplina)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE horario (
    entrada TIME NOT NULL,
    id_sala int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    nome_disciplina VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    compartilhada int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_sala, entrada),
    FOREIGN KEY (nome_disciplina) REFERENCES disciplina(nome_disciplina),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_sala) REFERENCES sala(id_sala),
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Com isso, você pode saber todas as informações de uma determinada sala (e portanto reconstruindo os seus dados originais) com a seguinte consulta:

```sql
SELECT entrada,
       (entrada + INTERVAL 30 MINUTES) AS saida,
       IF(ISNULL(nome_disciplina), 'Livre', 'Ocupada') AS status,
       nome_disciplina,
       compartilhada
FROM horario
WHERE id_sala = 1;
```

No caso da consulta acima, obviamente, vai trazer a tabela de horários da sala 1.

Agora, para resolver o problema que você tem em mãos, você pode se aproveitar da chave estrangeira ao usar o `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT m.id_sala,
       m.nome_disciplina,
       MIN(m.entrada),
       MAX(m.saida)
FROM (
    SELECT h.entrada AS entrada,
           (h.entrada + INTERVAL 30 MINUTES) AS saida,
           h.nome_disciplina AS nome_disciplina,
           h.id_sala AS id_sala
    FROM horario h
    INNER JOIN disciplina d ON h.nome_disciplina = d.nome_disciplina
    WHERE h.compartilhada = 1
) m
GROUP BY m.id_sala, m.nome_disciplina;
```

Se quiser realmente restringir o resultado por sala e/ou por disciplina, você pode acrescentar no `WHERE` do `SELECT` interno um `AND h.id_sala = 1` e/ou um `AND h.nome_disciplina = 'Geografia'`.

Comment: Cara, não está fazendo o query. Criei um novo banco de dados para testar esta aplicação, porém não funcionou. Agora está apresentando erro por não conseguir encontrar os dados. `mysql_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource`

Comment: Query: `$QueryBuscar = "SELECT entrada,(entrada + INTERVAL 30 MINUTES) AS saida,IF(ISNULL(nome_disciplina), 'Livre', 'Ocupada') AS status,nome_disciplina, compartilhada FROM horario WHERE id_sala = 1";`

Comment: Exec = `$ExeQrBuscar = mysqli_query($link, $QueryBuscar);

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ExeQrBuscar)){
    print_r ($res);
}`

Comment: @HugoChristian Onde é que você está usando `mysql_affected_rows()`?

Comment: Ah, mais um detalhe: Esse banco de dados é usado para consulta. A busca será usada para `inserir` em uma tabela de informações gerais para agendar uma aula nessa sala que está `compartilhada` por outro aluno. Consegue entender?

Comment: @HugoChristian Não consegui entender. Edite sua questão para esclarecer todos esses pontos colocando lá mais informações sobre o sistema que você está desenvolvendo.

Comment: usando o affected_rows não apresenta resultado @victor-stafusa

Comment: @Vitor-Fusa Ajudou bastante, não usei sua resposta, mas encontrei uma solução para esse problema com base na sua resposta, muito obrigado!