# grupo por consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma tabela **post** com um campo **categoria**, cada post que é inserido pode recebe mais que uma categoria:

`post1 categoria1, categoria2` 
`post2 categoria1, categoria3`

como posso realizar uma consulta sql para juntar as categorias duplicadas e ter um resultado assim:
`categoria1, categoria2, categoria 3`
ao invés de
`categoria1, categoria2, categoria1, categoria 3`

`SELECT post_category FROM`posts`group by post_category`
**resultado:** `Empresas, Ecônomia, ESPN, Ecônomia`
tenho apenas duas postagem cada uma com 2 categorias

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo do SQL que você está usando para que os demais usuários possam usá-la como base para formular uma boa resposta? Já adianto que a primeira coisa que pensei como solução é acrescentar um `DISTINCT` no seu `SELECT`.

Comment: acho que `DISTINCT` não vai funcionar porque as categorias estão dentro do mesmo campo, não manjo muito de mysql, só buscas simples

Comment: Essa coluna é multivalorada e está na primeira forma normal? Se for, então isso vai ser algo complicado. Se não for, então expliqque melhor como é que está. Veja mais detalhes no começo desta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151394/132

Comment: sim, é multivalorada, nesse caso então vou criar outra tabela

Answer (score -2):

o mais correto seria vc ter a seguinte estrutura..
post   categoria
post1 categoria1
post1 categoria2 
post2 categoria1
post2 categoria3
ai você conseguiria facilmente listar as categorias distintas de cada post..
mas neste caso pelo que percebi está entrando mais de uma categoria no mesmo campo e todas concatenadas. Mas como a estrutura já esta montada você pode usar a funcção splifn deste link [aqui](http://zavaschi.com/index.php/2009/06/repostagem-funo-split-no-sql-server/) e usar a função para gerar uma tabela e trazer assim os distintos de cada post.

Comment: Então Robson na verdade já resolvi o problema, como o @Victor Stafusa disse, o que achei mas correto foi normalizar o banco de dados e transformar esse campo "Categorias" em uma outra tabela assim facilito as consultas de modo geral!