# Criação Tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql

Recentemente comecei a estudar um pouco de [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), e resolvi criar uma tabela de cadastrados aqui no clube que faço parte.

```
Create database Clube
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_general_ci;

use Clube;

create table Cadastrados(
Nome varchar(50),
Sexo enum('M', 'F'),
Matricula varchar(9),
Curso enum('Arquitetura e Urbanismo', 'Engenharia Ambiental', 'Engenharia Civil', 'Engenharia de Controle e Automação', 'Engenharia de Minas', 'Engenharia de Produção', 'Engenharia Geológica', 'Engenharia Mecânica', 'Engenharia Metalúrgica', 'Outro'),
Endereco varchar(50),
CPF varchar(15),
RG varchar(15),
Aniversario date,
Email varchar(30),
Telefone varchar(20),
Socio enum('SIM', 'NÃO'),
Atleta enum('SIM', 'NÃO'),
Treinador enum('SIM', 'NÃO'),
primary key (Matricula)
)default charset = utf8;
```

Até ai tudo bem. Consegui criar a tabela, usei o `insert into` para adicionar valores e testar os campos, mas agora que minhas dúvidas começam:

Na coluna "Atleta", um cadastrado meu pode ter até 5 modalidades. Como eu faria dar certo?

De primeira eu pensei em criar outra tabela e utilizar o comando enum para resolver o problema.

```
Create table Atletas(
Modalidade1 enum('Atletismo', 'Basquete', 'Futebol de Campo', 'Futsal', 'Futebol Americano', 'Handebol', 'Natação'),
Modalidade2 enum('Atletismo', 'Basquete', 'Futebol de Campo', 'Futsal', 'Futebol Americano', 'Handebol', 'Natação'),
Modalidade3 enum('Atletismo', 'Basquete', 'Futebol de Campo', 'Futsal', 'Futebol Americano', 'Handebol', 'Natação'),
Modalidade4 enum('Atletismo', 'Basquete', 'Futebol de Campo', 'Futsal', 'Futebol Americano', 'Handebol', 'Natação'),
Modalidade5 enum('Atletismo', 'Basquete', 'Futebol de Campo', 'Futsal', 'Futebol Americano', 'Handebol', 'Natação')
)default charset = utf8;
```

E depois tentar ligar as duas tabelas.

Mas estou achando muito "porco" esse meio. Até porque quando eu adiciona algo com o `insert into`, não consigo modificá-lo depois, nem mesmo colocar o valor default como vazio.

Comment: Na minha opiniao terias que criar uma tabela com as modalidades, e outra sendo a relacao entra a tabela modalidade e o teu cadastrado atleta

Comment: Você poderia trocar atleta para modalidade usar como chave estrangeira, e conectar em outra tabela, e na outra tabela terá uma chave estrangeira do id do cadastrado em questão junto com a modalidade que ele utiliza.
Não sei se ficou claro, se tiver alguma dúvida só perguntar ^^

Comment: Se você colocar as informações das modalidades em outra tabela você pode ter 0..n modalidades, usando chave estrangeira para obter as modalidades cadastradas, o esquema ficaria assim [![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yquS4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yquS4.png) Recomendo fazer algo parecido também com Cursos, para não ficar limitado aos cursos do enum

Comment: Cria outra tabela e relaciona que da certo

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%c3%a9-normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-banco-de-dados)

Answer (score -1):

Complementando a resposta do Antonio, esse é um caso de relacionamento Many-to-many (muitos para muitos). Para esses casos, geralmente você precisa criar uma tabela-relacionamento entre outras tabelas. Por exemplo:

Um membro do seu clube pode estar associado a várias modalidades, assim como uma modalidade pode estar associada a vários membros. Desta forma você possui duas *tabelas entidades* (Cadastrados e Modalidades), e deve criar uma *tabela relacionamento* (Atleta) contendo chaves estrangeiras referenciando as outras duas tabelas. Ficando dessa forma (imagem minimalista):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma, um exemplo de dados pode ser:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso significa que temos 3 membros (JOÃO, PEDRO e MARIA), 7 modalidades (Atletismo, Basquete, Futebol de Campo, Futsal, Futebol Americano, Handebol e Natação). E a tabela Atleta é o relacionamento entre estas duas informando que:

JOÃO (Matrícula: 123456789) pratica:

- Atletismo (id: 1);
- Futsal (id: 3);
- Natação (id: 6).

PEDRO (Matrícula: 987654321) pratica:

- Handebol (id: 5)
- Futebol Americano (id: 4).

e MARIA (Matrícula: 475643241) não pratica nenhuma modalidade.