# Por que criar uma tabela no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou aprendendo a trabalhar com MySQL e estou vendo alguns exemplos de como trabalhar com mais de uma tabela, conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
Id      Nome        Faculdade_id
101     Amanda      11
102     Bianca      12
103     Carla       13
104     Daniela     12
105     Edna        11

id      Faculdade   Estado
11      UERJ        RJ
12      UESP        SP
13      UNEB        BA
```

O objetivo do exemplo é aprender a utilizar mais de uma tabela, mas bateu uma duvida, na pratica qual a vantagem de criar duas tabelas ao invés de simplesmente criar outras colunas?

No exemplo que coloquei imagino que não haja vantagem mais se as tabelas estiverem varias colunas e centenas de linhas, seria realmente mais rápido usar duas tabelas ao invés de incluir mais colunas?

Comment: Cai nesse assunto => [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao criar uma segunda tabela você pode dividir informações, imagine que você tem todos os dados pertinentes a uma pessoa, cerca de 20 metadados por exemplo e um desses metadados se refere a faculdade que a que essa pessoa frequentou, manter todas a informações da faculdade na tabela de pessoas não é semanticamente correto além de fazer com que o banco de dados traga mais informações caso nenhum filtro seja aplicado. Se houverem 15 metadados referentes a faculdade a tabela de pessoas pode ficar muito grande e vai ficar mais difícil trabalha com ela.