# É realmente necessário criar uma 3ª tabela auxiliar em relacionamentos N-N?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Em vários locais eu vejo que quando se tem um relacionamento `N`-`N` (se não me falha a memória) recomenda-se criar uma 3ª tabela auxiliar e então posteriormente irá ser transformado em um relacionamento 1 - 1 (também se não me falha a memória).

- Por que dizem que precisa fazer isso? Tem a ver com normalização?
- É realmente necessário? O que se perde fazendo isso? E o que se ganha?
- Essa recomendação é somente para MySQL?

Comment: Cliente - Pedido, acredito que não seja N-N, ou um pedido vai ter mais de um cliente ?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/91)

Comment: O seu caso ai de `Cliente` e `Pedido` ser N:N é só em casos bem específicos no qual o sistema exige isso. Já as tabelas `Pedido` e `Produto`, pode ter um relacionamento N:N criando a tabela `PedidoProdutos`.

Comment: Sem a tabela, como você faria esse relacionamento?

Comment: Exemplos bons são reais, porque coisas inventadas assim terão como resposta que isto é errado. Uma das vantagens do relacional é poder enxergar os dados de várias formas diferentes simplificadamente e com performance. Essa tabela auxiliar serviria para isso. Se não precisa acessar os dados assim, não precisa dela.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Por que dizem que precisa fazer isso?

Para ter ganhos, veja abaixo.

> Tem a ver com normalização?

Sim.

> É realmente necessário?

Não, mas quase. É muito difícil fazer certo sem essa tabela de associação, e em alguns casos inviável, ainda que possível.

> O que se perde fazendo isso?

Necessidade de um `JOIN` é o principal

> E o que se ganha?

Flexibilidade de consulta, performance, facilidade de manutenção, consistência, só pra citar o principal.

> Essa recomendação é somente para MySQL?

Não.

## Detalhes

Um bom exemplo é **produtos X fornecedores**. Um fornecedor muito provavelmente fornece vários produtos e é muito comum que um produto seja fornecido por vários fornecedores, principalmente no atacado e varejo, mas também na indústria quando o produto é *commodity* ou tem substituição perfeita.

Como você pode vincular ambos? Uma forma é colocar no próprio produto todos os fornecedores que podem fornecê-lo. Pode parecer esquisito, mas muitas vezes funciona porque costuma ser poucos fornecedores. Pelo menos em tabelas com tamanho variável isso não é um grande problema. Claro que possui desvantagens. O acesso não é tão simples, pode ter que fazer certos contorcionismos para pegar o que deseja, saber quem fornece o que, pode ter problemas de performance, inclusive porque fica muito dado junto que não é necessário complicando o cache e as leituras que serão mais frequentes.

Piora muito do outro lado. Se colocar todos os produtos que um fornecedor fornece pode ser um monstro, é comum fornecedores terem milhares de produtos.

Uma outra solução é repetir os cadastros, ou seja ter uma linha para cada produto e fornecedor que o fornece. Isto fere a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101), cria duplicação de dados, pode ser uma situação até pior em termos de performance, consumo de memória, e malabarismo para se chegar onde quer.

A solução que costuma funcionar melhor é ter uma tabela de amarração onde basicamente consta a relação de fornecedor e produto. É pequeno, com os índices certos é de acesso rápido, não prejudica o cache, não carrega demais, não duplica, não é tão difícil consultar os dados assim, permite acessos dos dois lados de forma simples na maioria dos casos.

Claro que perde um pouco a localidade, exige algum `JOIN` na maioria das consultas, é preciso garantir que a atualização de dados seja feita corretamente nessa tabela também, mas não muito diferente das outras soluções, pelo menos é uma operação dentro dos padrões normais relacionais que precisamos.

Isso vale para qualquer banco de dados relacional.

Pensa como funciona isso em objetos na memória. Você terá no fornecedor uma lista com os produtos que eles fornece. E no produto terá uma lista com os fornecedores dele. Eles fazem parte do mesmo objeto? Ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, não faz, a lista é outro objeto. Note que provavelmente terá duas listas. Dá para fazer o mesmo no banco de dados, mas não vejo vantagem, dá trabalho resolver assim. É melhor uma tabela só com dois índices.

Eu sou um pouco crítico do uso de bancos de dados não relacionais porque a imensa maioria dos problemas que resolvemos com DBs são relacionais. Quando começam usar tecnologias não relacionais para isso trazem problemas não encontrados quando a tecnologia é relacional, aí para resolver começam criar outras tecnologias e metodologias para consertar a escolha inadequada da tecnologia.

Não cabe aqui, mas modelos não relacionais costumam ser úteis em uma parte do problema, raramente no problema todo, por isso com a evolução dos DBs relacionais para trabalhar melhor com dados não relacionais se torna uma solução perfeita. Mesmo problemas que possuem essa característica, muitas vezes são adaptados para se encaixar no modelo, muitas vezes prejudicando a experiência com o usuário, ainda que possa simplificar um pouco o desenvolvimento.

Então se o problema é esse, quase sempre terá que fazer assim, salvo se o problema possa ser resolvido de outra forma com tranquilidade. Mesmo que não precise desta tabela de amarração, quem sabe um dia precisará e aí terá que fazer profundas mudanças no banco de dados. Poucas aplicações estão preparadas para trabalhar com estruturas físicas de base de dados diferentes, o que até é um erro conceitual, mas aí não sei o quanto o pragmatismo tem que prevalecer mesmo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 10):

Primeiramente irei citar, com base em livros, conceitos sobre cardinalidades `N x N` para depois responder suas perguntas:

Segundo os autores,  quando relações entre duas tabelas forem `N x N`:

- [Leite, Mario (2008)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=eIbxWBmdI34C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Na cardinalidade `N - N` é muito difícil para o programador converter essa semântica em código, pois isso, o que se faz é criar uma nova entidade (Entidade-Associativa) que se relacionará com as entidades origens com a cardinalidade `N - 1`.

- [Costa, Rogério Luiz de C. (2006)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=3Lxv-q6-S3MC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Quando a cardinalidade é `N - N` deve ser criada uma nova entidade para representar o relacionamento [...] entre as entidades envolvidas no relacionamento.

- [Morelli, Eduardo Terra (2009)](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=alKECgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Inicialmente todo relacionamento `N - N` tem que ser quebrados em relacionamento `N - 1`, mais uma tabela. Isto porque resulta impossível relacionamentos múltiplas (`N - N` ) em banco de dados real.

**Considerações**

Em nenhum momento nos livros citados foi explicado, de fato, porque devemos utilizar a criação de mais uma entidade em relacionamentos `N - N`.

Entretanto, pude perceber que, todos concordaram que adotar a tratativa de mais uma entidade reduz a complexabilidade para implementar a lógica, tanto na hora de codificar, quanto ao fato de salvar, manter e extrair as informações dos *SGBD RELACIONAIS*.

Agora sobre suas perguntas:

**Porque dizem que precisa fazer isso? Tem a ver com normalização?**
Você não precisa fazer a adição de mais uma tabela em relacionamentos `N - N`. Na minha opinião é mais uma questão de uma melhor tratativa com o intuito de diminuir a complexabilidade na hora de codificar e trabalhar os dados nos *SGBD's* relacionais.

**É realmente necessário? O que se perde fazendo isso? E o que se ganha?**
Na hora de criar o modelo de relacionamento de um projeto eu tenho como foco/tratativa ou melhores práticas, chame como quiser, criar um sistema que atenda a necessidade da maneira mais simples possível para que a manutenção seja, também, mais simples possível.

Sobre o que se perde ou ganha. Acredito que, com base nas citações, seja a produtividade na hora de codificar. Posso estar errado, mas relações `1 - N ou N - 1` são menos complexas para se tratar. Se eu usar a "convenção" de criar uma entidade para relações `N - N` que diminua minha complexabilidade, estarei ganhando em produtividade.

**Essa recomendação é somente para MySQL?**
Não.

> Segundo Morelli a modelagem relacional (MER) foi criado
>   para descrever os dados armazenados em tabelas.

Ou seja, essa convenção é para qualquer SGBD relacional.