# Existe uma forma melhor de construir um grafo?

Tags: python, grafo

Possuo uma lista de artigos com suas respectivas tags:

```
artigo1 ['a','b','c']
artigo2 ['a','d','f']
artigo3 ['z','d','f']
...
```

Preciso criar um grafo que irá relacionar todos os artigos pelas tags. No final terei que ter essa estrutura (Não pode ser outra):

```
artigo1: ['artigo2']
artigo2: ['artigo1','artigo3']
artigo3: ['artigo2']
...
```

Inicialmente fiz dois `for`:

```
for i in range(0,len(vertices)):
    for j in range(i,len(vertices)):
        for tag in vertices[i].tags:
            if(tag in vertices[j].tags):
                vertices[i].neighbor.append(vertices[j].uid)
                vertices[j].neighbor.append(vertices[i].uid)
```

Funcionar funciona porém meu arquivo possui 5.500.000 de artigos e irá gastar uma eternidade pois a complexidade é O((n^2)/2). Existe uma forma melhor de realizar essa computação?

Comment: Tem como melhorar sim. Eu fiz um construtor de grafo em Java usando chaves e mapas. Vou mandar a ideia aqui, mas não código final. A velocidade assintótica vai depender basicamente da estrutura para guardar e para resgatar os dados

Comment: Não sei se te ajuda, mas já deu uma olhada no igraph? Link: http://igraph.org/python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme eu tinha [comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275262/existe-uma-forma-melhor-de-construir-um-grafo#comment562885_275262), eu fiz um esquema de montagem de grafos em Java baseado em mapas, desde que cada nó tivesse uma chave que o identificasse. O seu caso é ligeiramente diferente, pois cada nó aqui tem várias chaves que o identificam. Você também pode ver como um grafo bipartido a sua questão em específico. Vou focar no grafo bipartido.

> A propósito, enquanto escrevia esta resposta, percebi que o seu problema é algo básico para sistemas de bancos de dados dever tratar. Percebi que os bancos de dados tratam do seu problema como uma relação entre duas tabelas, muitos para muitos. E as arestas entre as duas entidades é representada na tabela de ligação. [Veja mais aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/221018/64969). Imagina se para toda ligação entre 2 entidades muitos-muitos fosse de velocidade quadrática?

Você tem dois tipos de dados. O primeiro tipo de dado é `artigo`. O segundo tipo de dado é `tag`. Um artigo possui várias tags, e uma tag pode estar em vários artigos. Mas aqui não há ligação `tag -- tag` ou `artigo -- artigo`.

> Ainda é possível existir essas ligações e continuar com um grafo bipartido *em termos*. Mas para isso precisamos considerar que existem ligações de tipos distintos e que o grafo é bipartido na classe de ligações *tags pertencentes a artigos*.

Um exemplo de grafo bipartido:

[image: grafo bipartido]

Você já tem aqui a navegação entre os artigos e as tags, nessa direção. Mas para fazer a navegação completa você precisa navegar das tags para os artigos. Como fazer isso? Que tal com um *multimapa*? Resumindo, um multimapa é uma estrutura de dados que, para uma única chave, retorna uma coleção de elementos.

> Tratei de como implementar um multimapa [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254612/64969), com uma análise do que é essa estrutura de dados [nesta outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240048/64969).

Então, montamos o multimapa `mm_tags_artigos` conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/254612/64969) e podemos acessar todos os artigos relacionados a uma determinada tag fazendo um acesso a mapa. O seu exemplo traria exatamente:

```
mm_tags_artigos['a'] ==> [ artigo1 , artigo2 ]
mm_tags_artigos['b'] ==> [ artigo1 ]
mm_tags_artigos['c'] ==> [ artigo1 ]
mm_tags_artigos['d'] ==> [ artigo2 , artigo3 ]
mm_tags_artigos['f'] ==> [ artigo2 , artigo3 ]
mm_tags_artigos['z'] ==> [ artigo3 ]
```

Então, como saber quais são os artigos relacionados a um outro? Bem, pegamos todas as arestas a duas posições de distâncias no grafo bipartido. Como o grafo é bipartido, tudo a uma distância par de arestas de um artigo é um artigo também. Ao pegar todos os artigos a dois saltos de distância do meu artigo alvo, teremos o seguinte conjunto:

[image: Descrição matemática de artigos a dois saltos de distância]

Aqui, `S_artigo` é o conjunto formado por todos os artigos que se relacionam diretamente com as tags do artigo `artigo`. Claro, aqui o próprio artigo também seria retornado, então bastaria remover o artigo que se deseja saber os relacionados desse conjunto.

Basicamente, após ter o multimapa montado, bastaria da seguinte linha que então você obteria todos os artigos relacionados ao artigo `x` (obrigado ao [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) por me mostrar o `itertools.chain`):

```
[artigo_vizinho for artigo_vizinho, g in groupby(sorted(chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]), key = str)) if artigo_vizinho != x]
```

Isso vai retornar uma lista com todos os artigos vizinhos, alcançados a partir das tags de `x`. Explicando cada passo, de dentro pra fora:

```
mm_tag_artigo[tag]
```

Estou pegando uma lista com todos os artigo que possuem a tag `tag`. `mm_tag_artigo` é o multimapa que, dada uma tag, retorna a lista de artigos associada a ela.

```
[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]
```

Para cada tag que `x` contenha, eu retorno uma lista com seus vizinhos. Se `x` fosse o `artigo2` do exemplo, os elementos seriam mais ou menos esses:

```
[
  # para a tag 'a'
  [artigo1, artigo2],

  # para a tag 'd'
  [artigo2, artigo3],

  # para a tag 'f'
  [artigo2, artigo3]
]
```

Se fosse `artigo1`:

```
[
  # para a tag 'a'
  [artigo1, artigo2],

  # para a tag 'b'
  [artigo1],

  # para a tag 'c'
  [artigo1]
]
```

```
*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]
```

Usando o operador `explode` antes da lista, para que cada elemento da lista seja passado como um argumento distinto da função que chama.

```
chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors])
```

Aqui estou juntando as listas obtidas em um único iterável. Para `x = artigo2`, obteríamos algo nesse formato:

```
[ artigo1, artigo2, artigo2, artigo3, artigo2, artigo3 ]
```

Já para `x = artigo1`:

```
[ artigo1, artigo2, artigo1, artigo1 ]
```

Documentação do `chain`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

```
sorted(chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]), key = str)
```

Agora estou ordenando o resultado obtido. Talvez objetos do tipo `artigo` não sejam diretamente ordenáveis, então estou usando como chave classificatória sua representação de string para realizar a ordenação (`key = str`). Fiz testes para quando não há sobrescrita do método `__str__` da classe de artigos, portanto ele imprime uma string distinta para cada objeto.

Documentação do `sorted`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

> Claro, se o método `__str__` de um artigo for sobrescrito de modo a permitir dois objetos distintos com a mesma representação, aí danou o próximo passo.

A intenção de ordenar aqui é apenas para poder agrupar os objetos unicamente, que isso é feito no próximo passo:

```
groupby(sorted(chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]), key = str))
```

Estou agrupando os elementos de modo que eu consiga obter apenas um de cada, sem precisar de repetições. Note que essa função funciona em tempo linear, como se fosse o comando `uniq` do Unix, agrupando apenas elementos consecutivos.

Documentação do `groupby`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
artigo_vizinho for artigo_vizinho, g in groupby(sorted(chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]), key = str))
```

A função `groupby` retorna uma lista de tuplas, sendo elas:

- o elemento agrupador
- o grupo formado por aquele elemento

Não nos interessa o grupo, então estou descartando-o, ficando apenas com o agrupador, que no caso é um artigo chamado de `artigo_vizinho`.

```
artigo_vizinho for artigo_vizinho, g in groupby(sorted(chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]), key = str)) if artigo_vizinho != x
```

Apenas condicionando pegar os artigos vizinhos, sem repetir o artigo `x`.

```
[artigo_vizinho for artigo_vizinho, g in groupby(sorted(chain(*[mm_tag_artigo[tag] for tag in x.neighbors]), key = str)) if artigo_vizinho != x]
```

Bem, transformando esse resultado obtido em lista. Não tem muito porquê disso, mania minha mesmo.

Só como detalhe, não se esqueça de que `sorted` é *built-in*, já está disponível para o Python, enquanto que `chain` e `groupby` precisam ser importados, eles estão no módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools). Para usar do jeito que usei, importe assim: `from itertools import chain, groupby`.

Veja funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/oSknih).

Comment: Eu entendi toda a ideia de sua resposta, estava pensando algo parecido, mas eu parei até em criar o multimapa. A unica coisa que não entendi foi o '*' e o fato da necessidade de ordenar(Talvez seria pro chain?).

Comment: @ViniciusMorais o ordenar na verdade é por conta do `groupby`. Tem mais detalhes na documentação. Sobre o `*`, tente os seguintes experimentos: `chain([1,2,3], [4,5,6])` (simulando com o asterisco); `chain([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])` (simulando sem o asterisco)

Comment: Outra coisa, qual seria a nova complexidade?

Comment: @ViniciusMorais puts, esqueci disso! Mal aí... dependendo da eficiência da busca e da inserção do dicionário, acho que é `o(n + e log e + e)`, onde `e` é a quantidade de arestas média por vértice. Tem alternativa com tempo assintótico menor ainda, usando um grafo apenas de artigos, não um grafo bipartido, mas a alternativa é um passo de abstração a mais e não consegui digitar ontem, estava cansado

Comment: Muito obrigado.