# Selecionar registro que contenha resultado equivalente a uma variável

Tags: php, mysql, query, select

Tenho uma coluna em minha tabela mysql, em que a mesma se chama "cargos", onde vários valores em *int* são colocados lá, porém, com a "|" de divisão.

Exemplo: 8|19|10|20|

E cada número representa uma categoria.

Gostaria de fazer um SELECT onde eu tendo apenas uma número, selecionaria os registros que tivessem esse número no meio.

Exemplo: Escolhi o número 8 para fazer o select na tabela, onde minha coluna *cargos* é igual a 8|19|10|20|, como ela tem o número 8, a mesma retornará positivamente.

```
<?php
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''; // numero que vou selecionar
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE cargos LIKE '%$id%' OR cargos = '$id' ORDER BY id");
while($ver = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

?>
```

Tentei fazer desta forma, porém não deu certo com o "LIKE".

Comment: Acredito que o ideal é reformular totalmente o banco de dados, [não faz sentido armazenar vários valores numa única coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%C3%A9-normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados/151394#151394). O banco de dados suporta várias tabela, seria bem mais fácil e rápido se criasse uma tabela "cargos". Existe como resolver o problema, mas isso não parece ser uma boa ideia.

Comment: Veja, tem certeza que não está funcionando ? [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d13d5/3) .... Claro que informar exemplo `cargos = "4"` não ira funcionar, tem que usar o `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

Como nosso amigo @Inkeliz mencionou, o ideal é reformular o banco de dados e criar uma tabela para associar o cargo com o usuário. Mas se não for possível fazer essa reformulação, você pode driblar esse problema da seguinte forma:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE (cargos LIKE '%|$id|%' OR cargos LIKE '%|$id' OR cargos LIKE '$id|%') ORDER BY id");
```

O problema de fazer dessa forma é que vai perder a velocidade da consulta.