# Como modelar relação n-para-n corretamente? Mulheres também terem amizade com homens e não somente homens terem amizade com mulheres

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá, quero fazer o seguinte: Criar no MySQL a relação n-para-n onde homens tem amizades com mulheres e mulheres também tenham amizades com homens.

Exemplo:

**João** tem *amizade* com **Fernanda**, mas, **Fernanda** não tem amizade com **João** e sim com **Carlos**, *mas* **João** continua tendo amizade com **Fernanda**.

Eu criei um modelo n-para-n onde os homens tenha amizade com as mulheres, mas não conseguir fazer mulheres terem amizade com os homens e vice-versa.

Veja meu script SQL a seguir:

```
create database pessoas;
use pessoas;

create table homens (id int auto_increment, nome varchar(10), primary key (id));

create table mulheres (id int auto_increment, nome varchar(10), primary key (id));

create table amizades (id int auto_increment, homem_id int, mulher_id int,
primary key(id),
foreign key(homem_id) references homens(id),
foreign key(mulher_id) references mulheres(id));

insert into homens values 
(default, 'Joao'),
(default, 'Flavio'),
(default, 'Carlos');

insert into mulheres values 
(default,'Ana'),
(default,'Fernanda'),
(default,'Julia');

insert into amizades values 
(default, 1, 2),
(default, 2, 1),
(default, 3, 3);

/* join com 3 tabelas, aparecer o id e nome do homem e depois o id e nome da mulher de quem o homem é amigo */
select homens.id, homens.nome, mulheres.id, mulheres.nome from homens join amizades on homens.id = amizades.homem_id
join mulheres on amizades.mulher_id = mulheres.id order by homens.id;
```

Eu quero uma relação explícita no banco de dados para eu saber quem tem amizade com quem e não somente simular essa relação mudando a ordem das colunas no `SELECT`, entenderam? Qual melhor forma de fazer isso?

Comment: Faria uma tabela só PESSOA (ID,NOME,SEXO) outra de AMIZADE (ID_DE,ID_PARA) e por TRIGGER testaria se os sexos são diferentes

Comment: Mais quero saber em relação n-para-n algo explícito e não testando os sexos.

Comment: apenas não vi a necessidade de duas tabelas, a relação seria mantida.

Comment: @Motta Valeu ai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu criaria duas tabelas de relacionamento: `amizades_hm` e `amizades_mh`. Ambas tem apenas dois campos: `homem_id` e `mulher_id`, sendo ambos parte da chave primária em ambas as tabelas:

Eis o script para criar o banco de dados:

```
CREATE DATABASE pessoas;
USE pessoas;

CREATE table homens (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE table mulheres (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE table amizades_hm (
    homem_id INT,
    mulher_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (homem_id, mulher_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (homem_id) REFERENCES homens(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (mulher_id) REFERENCES mulheres(id)
);

CREATE table amizades_mh (
    homem_id INT,
    mulher_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (homem_id, mulher_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (homem_id) REFERENCES homens(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (mulher_id) REFERENCES mulheres(id)
);
```

Para inserir dados nele:

```
INSERT INTO homens VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Joao'), (DEFAULT, 'Flavio'), (DEFAULT, 'Carlos');
INSERT INTO mulheres VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Ana'), (DEFAULT, 'Fernanda'), (DEFAULT, 'Julia');
INSERT INTO amizades_hm VALUES
    (1 /*Joao*/, 2 /*Fernanda*/),
    (2 /*Flavio*/, 1 /*Ana*/),
    (3 /*Carlos*/, 3 /*Julia*/);
INSERT INTO amizades_mh VALUES
    (2 /*Flavio*/, 2 /*Fernanda*/),
    (2 /*Flavio*/, 3 /*Julia*/),
    (3 /*Carlos*/, 3 /*Julia*/);
```

Para ler quais são as amigas de cada homem:

```
SELECT homens.id, homens.nome, mulheres.id, mulheres.nome
FROM homens
INNER JOIN amizades_hm ON homens.id = amizades_hm.homem_id
INNER JOIN mulheres ON amizades_hm.mulher_id = mulheres.id
ORDER BY homens.id;
```

Saída:

```
id | nome   | id | nome
---+--------+----+--------
1  | Joao   | 2  | Fenanda
2  | Flavio | 2  | Ana
3  | Carlos | 3  | Julia
```

Para ler quais são os amigos de cada mulher:

```
SELECT mulheres.id, mulheres.nome, homens.id, homens.nome
FROM mulheres
INNER JOIN amizades_mh ON mulheres.id = amizades_mh.mulher_id
INNER JOIN homens ON amizades_mh.homem_id = homens.id
ORDER BY mulheres.id;
```

Saída:

```
id | nome     | id | nome
---+----------+----+-------
1  | Fernanda | 2  | Flavio
3  | Julia    | 2  | Flavio
3  | Julia    | 3  | Carlos
```

Para ler todas as amizades:

```
SELECT a.origem_tipo, a.origem_id, a.origem_nome, a.destino_tipo, a.destino_id, a.destino_nome
FROM (
    SELECT
        'Homem' AS origem_tipo,
        h1.id AS origem_id,
        h1.nome AS origem_nome,
        'Mulher' AS destino_tipo,
        m1.id AS destino_id,
        m1.nome AS destino_nome
    FROM homens h1
    INNER JOIN amizades_hm hm ON h1.id = hm.homem_id
    INNER JOIN mulheres m1 ON hm.mulher_id = m1.id
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT
            'Mulher' AS origem_tipo,
            m2.id AS origem_id,
            m2.nome AS origem_nome,
            'Homem' AS destino_tipo,
            h2.id AS destino_id,
            h2.nome AS destino_nome
        FROM mulheres m2
        INNER JOIN amizades_mh mh ON m2.id = mh.mulher_id
        INNER JOIN homens h2 ON mh.homem_id = h2.id
    )
) a
ORDER BY a.origem_tipo, a.origem_id;
```

Saída:

```
origem_tipo | origem_id | origem_nome | destino_tipo | destino_id | destino_nome
------------+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+--------------
Homem       | 1         | Joao        | Mulher       | 2          | Fernanda
Homem       | 2         | Flavio      | Mulher       | 1          | Ana
Homem       | 3         | Carlos      | Mulher       | 3          | Julia
Mulher      | 2         | Fernanda    | Homem        | 2          | Flavio
Mulher      | 3         | Julia       | Homem        | 3          | Carlos
Mulher      | 3         | Julia       | Homem        | 2          | Flavio
```

Comment: Dessa sua forma tinha pensado, mas veio a dúvida se de acordo com meu script é possível relação h-com-m e m-com-h usando 3 tabelas, a terceira sendo de relacionamento. Esse modelo de aplicar 2 campo como chave primaria é correto? Eu sei que somente 1 campo pode ser chave primaria.

Comment: @Bruno Não é verdade essa afirmação de que somente um campo pode ser chave primária. Essa forma é a forma padrão de aplicar relacionamentros N-para-N: uma tabela intermediária que contém todos os campos chaves primária de cada uma das tabelas relacionadas como chave estrangeiras e todos eles são chaves primárias e nada mais do que isso. Veja mais [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/132).

Comment: @Bruno Daria para colocar as duas em uma só tabela ao acrescentar um campo a mais, mas decidi manter assim exatamente por conta dessa ser a forma padrão de relacionamento N-para-N e devido ao fato de muitas ferramentas de modelagem identificá-la como tal por ter esse exato formato.

Comment: Obrigado então! Porém meu script tem erro, tem 3 campos na tabela intermediaria, 1 campo id como chave primaria, 1 campo homem_id como chave estrangeira e 1 campo mulher_id também como chave estrangeira

Comment: @Bruno Nesse caso você modelou uma outra entidade que tem um relacionamento com um homem e com uma mulher. O problema na sua modelagem é que eu posso fazer `INSERT INTO amizades (DEFAULT, 1, 2), (DEFAULT, 1, 2);` e daí temos que João e Fernanda são amigos 2 vezes - mas não tem muito sentido alguém ser amigo de alguém mais do que uma vez.

Comment: @Bruno Ah, editei a minha resposta para acrecsentar a saída dos `SELECT`s e coloquei um `SELECT` mais complexo para listar todas as amizades.

Comment: valeu, obs: coloquei na tabela amizade que a primary key é a chave estrangeira de homem e mulher e o registro não se repetiu, naturalmente id como primary key o registro se repete? Porque aprendi que o campo id como primary key o registro não se repete.

Comment: @Bruno Sim. O conjunto de campos da primary key é sempre único, o banco de dados não permite você inserir dois registros com a mesma primary key. Como você tem uma chave composta, significa que não vai ser possível repetir os mesmos valores em todos os campos. Ou seja, você vai poder cadastrar `(2, 3)` apenas uma vez, mas ter o `(2, 3)` cadastrado não te impede de cadastrar `(2, 2)` ou `(1, 3)` porque nesse caso vai haver colisão em apenas alguns dos campos da chave primária, e não em todos.

Comment: me tira uma dúvida, fiz uma tabela e fiz 2 campos, uma id para primary key e outra como nome. Assim conseguir cadastrar meu nome 2 vezes mais o id foi diferente, como faço para ter realmente uma tupla como unica no banco de dados sem ter que usar UNIQUE? Alguém nas respostas disse que meu modelo está errado, pois seria permitido repetir a tupla. Sou recente nisso de SQL, mas percebi que um campo como primary key não está funcionando como achei antes de começar a trabalhar com SQL.

Comment: @Bruno A resposta seria exatamente usar `UNIQUE`. Outra possibilidade seria fazer o campo `nome` ser a chave primária. Entretanto, se o `nome` fosse a chave primária, quando alguém mudasse de nome (ex: correção de erro de digitação ou mulher que casou e adotou o sobrenome do marido), você quebraria a cara para alterar todas as chaves estrangeiras, e por causa disso não é boa ideia fazer o nome ser chave primária. Logo, a alternativa seria fazer o nome ser `UNIQUE`. Entretanto, há muitas pessoas homônimas por aí (será que só existe um "João da Silva"?) - E portanto, o ideal é [continua...]

Comment: [continuação] que você aceite o fato de que o nome pode repetir. Muitos sistemas reais colocam uma restrição `UNIQUE` no conjunto "*nome + nome da mãe + data de nascimento*" para garantir a unicidade, de forma a acreditar que não devem existir duas pessoas com o mesmo nome, filho(a)s de mães com o mesmo nome e nascido(a)s no mesmo dia. Apesar disso, já li uma notícia uma vez de alguém que teve um problema com o governo porque aconteceu exatamente isso.

Comment: Entendi, mais está complicado, pensei que chave primaria era para o registro não se repetir. adicionei na minha tabela o index unique para nome e para o novo campo sobrenome, então o id, nome e sobrenome não se repetiu, mas não sei qual a forma correta para resolver isso.

Comment: @Bruno A chave-primária serve para identificar um registro de forma única e inequívoca, mas nada diz quanto aos campos que não estão na chave primária. Os valores dos campos da chave primária não podem se repetir, mas isso nada tem a dizer acerca dos demais campos. No seu caso o id não vai se repetir e o conjunto "*nome + sobrenome*" também não. Se você não considera o caso de homônimos, então tudo bem.

Comment: valeu, agora entendi sobre chave primaria! =)

Answer (score 0):

Uma relação n-para-n é sempre modelada com uma tabela auxiliar cuja chave primária é o conjunto das duas chaves estrangeiras ou uma chave única. Tecnicamente, sua solução está correta.

Primeiro, o modelo em questão não impede a relação: "(...)onde os homens tenha amizade com as mulheres, (...) mulheres terem amizade com os homens e vice-versa.", já que são possíveis as combinações h-h, m-m, h-m, m-h; ainda que os códigos coincidam.

Segundo,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para obter a interseção você pode:

1)

```
select 
    homens.id, homens.nome, mulheres.id, mulheres.nome 
from amizades join homens on homens.id = amizades.homem_id
              join mulheres on mulheres.id = amizades.mulher_id;
```

2) Ou,

```
select a.nome, b.nome
from
(select 
    homens.id, homens.nome
from amizades join homens on homens.id = amizades.homem_id) a
union
(select 
   mulheres.id, mulheres.nome 
from mulheres on mulheres.id = amizades.mulher_id) b
```

Em nenhum dos casos acima você precisará simular nenhuma relação. Espero ter entendido sua dúvida.

Comment: Isso de 2 campos serem chave primaria da tabela auxiliar, está correto? No meu script, somente o campo ID é chave primaria, e tem 2 campos que são chave estrangeira. Não entendi isso de 2 chave estrangeira ser a chave primaria da tabela auxiliar

Comment: Explico: você pode criar uma chave primária definida pela união de duas chaves primárias que venham de outra tabela. Assim: ID-amizade = (ID-homem + ID-mulher)