# O que é redundância de dados em banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Recentemente em minha disciplina de banco de dados na faculdade surgiu esta pergunta da qual eu fiquei com muita dúvida.

Comment: A redundância é redundante. Normalmente de dados. Normalmente de dados

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/91)

Answer (score 5):

Já foi dito que a redundância é ter a mesma informação em dois lugares diferentes.

Para definir um pouco melhor o que é a mesma informação em dois lugares pegue um saldo e o movimento da conta, há informação redundante aí. Pelo movimento você tem o saldo. Esta redundância é ruim? Não. Dá mais performance assim e simplifica o acesso.

Pegue os dados do cliente de uma nota fiscal emitida. É o mesmo que está no cadastro de cliente. Isto é redundante, é ruim? Não, é fundamental porque se mudar os dados do cliente não pode mudar na nota fiscal emitida.

Tem uma série de situações que a redundância faz parte do modelo, até mesmo para dar mais robustez e confiabilidade, além das questões já citadas.

A redundância traz o problema que é preciso alguma coordenação para manter a consistência. Ela deve ser evitada quando não é necessária, por isso existe a [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

*Redundância é quando um dado/informação é armazenada mais de uma vez desnecessariamente dentro de um Banco de Dados*, um exemplo grosseiro:

nome_funcionário e nome_pessoa, cada um em uma entidade diferente, isso é redundância, pois se tenho um funcionário que é uma pessoa, estarei armazenando duas vezes a mesma informação dentro do Banco.

**Mas como evitar redundâncias?**

Aplicando as formas normais ao projeto, geralmente as três primeiras já são suficientes (1FN, 2FN e 3FN)