# Como é representado um atributo multivalorado?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, google-play

Necessito realizar uma modelagem da Google Play como trabalho da univerisdade, um dos requisitos do trabalho é representar um multivalorado. como isso seria representado? Seria um tipo? ex:

```
Nome     Tipo
Genero   Set
```

nesse Caso Set é um multivalorado? Se puderem usar algum exemplo que envolva a google play irá ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Em banco de dados atributos multivalorados podem ser tipos especificos como um array, set, json etc. Na maioria dos casos é usando um varchar (que geralmente indica um problema na modelagem) como por exemplo em sistema de postagem onde tabela na de `posts` possui um campo de `categoria` que tem como valor os ids das categorias separados por vírgular ou qualquer outro delimitador.

Exemplo:

```
id|titulo|categoria|data
1 |teste |1,2,49   |2018-04-19
2 |teste2|5        |2018-04-01
3 |teste3|22,6,78,3|2018-04-05
```

**Relacionada:**

[O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/91)

Comment: Qual seria o Tipo de categoria? varchar?

Comment: @LeonardoFurtado nesse exemplo `varchar`, colunas multivaloradas são evidas pq são complicadas para pesquisar também precisam de manipulação extra para atualizar ou validar o valor.

Answer (score 1):

Sendo o seu trabalho relacionado com a Play Store, supoho que o `Género` sejam sejam "categorias" da loja estando estes valores já guardados na base de dados.

Se a resposta for sim, está perante um problema de *"muitos para muitos"* e não apenas de *"1 para muitos"*.

Para uma base de dados cumprir com a [1ª Forma Normal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados#Primeira_Forma_Normal) todos os valores das colunas das tabelas têm de ser atómicos, tendo por objectivo evitar a redundância de dados.

Como tal, a solução utilizada para este problema envolve a criação de uma tabela intermédia para armazenar a relação entre as duas entidades que partindo do princípio que as `Categorias` são previamente definidas seria algo semelhante a isto:

```
+---------+         +---------------------+        +-----------+
| EXEMPLO |         | EXEMPLO_CATEGORIA   |        | CATEGORIA |
+---------+ 1     * +---------------------+      1 +-----------+
|- ID [PK]|---------|- Exemplo [PK, FK]   |    +---|- ID [PK]  |
|- TITULO |         |- Categoria [PK, FK] |----+   |- Nome     |
|         |         |                     | *      |           |
|         |         |                     |        |           |
+---------+         +---------------------+        +-----------+
```

Qualquer das formas recomendo a leitura da pergunta [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%C3%A9-normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados) para ter uma ideia do que são as formas normais de uma base de dados relacional e as boas práticas a elas relacionadas.