# Contar quantidade de vezes que uma categoria e escolhida pelos clientes!

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela com as categorias, e cada cliente que se cadastra pode escolher ate 10 categorias correspondentes que corresponde ao trabalho dele!

Estas categorias na tabela do cliente ficam gravadas os ID's , preciso que cada categoria mostre na frente delas a quantidade de vezes que ela foi  marcada

Exemplo:

Comida (15)
Bebidas (5)
Cama (5)
Cozinha (20)

A tabela categorias e assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E a tabela dos clientes e gravado desta maneira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você salva as categorias dos clientes separadas por vírgulas no banco?

Comment: Se a resposta da pergunta acima for "sim", eu recomendo a leitura [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%C3%A9-normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Difícil saber a dúvida ou dificuldade. Seria bom editar e colocar alguns exemplos dos dados como estão na tabela, e o que tentou e não deu certo.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters - Li o contexto que vc me passou, porem estou criando uma funcionalidade no sistema que ja esta criado a uns dois anos. não posso recriar o que ja esta la, somente tentar implantar esta funcionalidade  de contagem de categorias.

Sobre sua segunda resposta, eu estou tentando criar do zero com os exemplos das tabelas, fiz uma de estado e funcionou corretamente coma função COUNT() do mysql, pois era apenas uma consulta na coluna, esta que sera separada por virgulas e o que esta me quebrando a cabeça de como fazer!

Comment: @MarcosPaulo como o Bacco disse, acho que a pergunta carece de mais exemplos.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, entendi, mais gostei muito da explicação da leitura que voce me passou, visto que precisarei de dar mais manutenções neste sistema, e provavelmente isso afetara no desempenho, vou conversar com o cliente para dar um tapa maior no sistema para evitar problemas futuros.
Vou conversar com ele mesmo que demore um pouco mais mas e melhor otimizar do que continuar da forma que esta

Comment: Então vou fechar esta pergunta que realizei e ver se consigo resolver com meu cliente, se não rolar eu reabro e coloco maiores explicações