# Dúvidas sobre modelagem de banco de dados, dualidade de ID's

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, id, chave-estrangeira

Estou criando um sistema voltado para escritório de advocacia, e no meio do desenvolvimento surgiu a seguinte situação:

Existem as seguintes tabelas (resumidas):

`TB_PROCESSO` possuindo:

```
IDPROCESSO
ID_CLIENTE
ID_REU
```

`TB_CLIENTE` possuindo:

```
IDCLIENTE
```

`TB_REU` possuindo:

```
IDREU
```

Na tabela `TB_CLIENTE` existem todas as informações pertinentes do cliente a ser atendido, enquanto a tabela `TB_REU` contem somente informações básicas, pois geralmente as informações do réu, não são tao relevantes.

No começo do projeto, eu criei o banco de dados com a seguinte lógica:

> O cliente sempre será o autor do processo, nunca réu.

Porém essa não é a realidade, há casos em que o cliente do escritório será o réu. Resumindo volta e meia o cliente será réu, outrora será o autor do processo.

Como iria se comportar a modelagem do banco de dados nesse caso?

Comment: Você poderia criar uma tabela que armazene o " tipo " (reú, cliente, autor...) e uma tabela "Pessoa"  que contenha o "tipo" como chave estrangeira. Por exemplo: Um novo Cadastro de processo irá conter uma pessoa do tipo (reú, autor, cliente...), bastando listar o tipo dentro do Pessoa...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Galera, pensei bastante sobre assunto, discuti com um brother meu e ele me deu a ideia de cadastrar tudo em uma tabela só, no caso a TB_CLIENTE. Chegamos a essa conclusão pois é uma maneira que soluciona todos impasses que eu estava tendo, **e até pq** por mais que seja improvável, um réu um dia tbm poderá ser um cliente, então cheguei a conclusão que seria desnecessário uma tabela de cadastro de réus. Muito obrigado aos que responderam, deixo aqui meu parecer. Se alguém tiver alguma critica, dica, manda ai que irei responder.

Comment: Então é o que eu falei, depende da análise de requisito, você descreveu uma coisa e decidiu fazer outra. E cria outro problema conceitual, cadastra uma pessoa que tem zero relação de cliente com o escritório como se fosse cliente. Quando conceitua errado, um dia precisa dar uma manutenção e complica tudo. Cliente é cliente, tem uma relação comercial com você, quem não tem não pode ser cadastrado ali. Você pode até ter um cadastro unificado para usar no cadastro de cliente ou de partes em processo, mas são papéis distintos. Inclusive vai empestear de gambiarras para tratar de forma diferente.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que basta mudar a tabela para `OutraParte` ou algum outro nome neutro. Inclusive há uma assimetria porque se `Reu` fosse o nome correto, a outra tabela seria `Autor`.

Em uma análise mais profunda talvez esses dois nomes sejam errados. Mas isso só você pode fazer e precisa de experiência para fazer certo.

Em alguns casos pode-se separar a ideia de cliente e de parte do processo (pela resposta do AP parece ser o correto), sendo o primeiro o contrato que você tem com a pessoa na prestação de serviço e o segundo sendo o envolvido no processo, inclusive pode ser que em algum caso a parte que você representa pode aparecer várias vezes ligadas ao mesmo cliente, que pode ser uma pessoa física, mas muito provavelmente será um pessoa jurídica. E aí essa tabela talvez seja `Parte` (note que eu não domino bem termos jurídicos e sem até que eles são meio contextuais de acordo com região e época).

O autor pode se tornar réu, tem ações que não existem réus. Enfim, tem muitas situações diferentes da que está sendo percebida na pergunta e na resposta do AP e se a modelagem não pensar em como os processados são de fato haverá grandes problemas.

Pode ser que os dados da parte sejam contextuais de acordo com o processo, mas não tenho como saber sem eu ser o analista. Pode ser, embora a pergunta dá a entender que não, as partes (seu cliente e a outra) possam estar em uma tabela única.

Portanto com mais informações minha recomendação é ter:

- Cliente (trata da relação comercial)
- Parte (trata da relação jurídica)

Opcional:

- Pessoa Física
- Pessoa Jurídica

Essa contendo os dados básicos obrigatórias de qualquer pessoa para ser associado com o papel de cliente ou como parte no processo.

A UI não precisa necessariamente separar, essa tabela é separada apenas por questão de [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101). Modelagem de DB é diferente de modelagem de UI.

Pode ser que nada disso seja adequado, mas é porque a analise e descrição postada aqui não é adequada.

Portanto você ainda nem viu a superfície do problema. E fazendo errado terá problemas no futuro.

Eu costumo dizer que taxonomia e ontologia é uma das coisas mais importantes do desenvolvimento de software. Sem dominar isso é difícil fazer um software correto, e mesmo quando funciona, muitas vezes não é o certo, e mesmo quando é certo, por coincidência não é algo muito desejável.

Considerando esta dificuldade básica haverá problemas bem mais complexos para lidar, provavelmente seria bom arrumar alguém mais experiente para fazer o software junto. Você está programando e fazendo a engenharia sem ter experiência anterior com alguém que mostre como é feito, e isto é bem complicado.

E se estiver ouvindo de algum cliente que é assim que se faz, esse cliente não está sabendo nem como ele próprio trabalho, o que é muito comum. Na nossa área precisamos conseguir "tirar" do futuro usuário o que muitas vezes nem ele se dava conta que era assim que ele trabalhava. É muito comum o usuário seguir processos sem se dar conta de como o faz, e tem casos de fazer errado ou fazer o que todo mundo faz sem questionar sobre os erros daquilo, ou ainda só não conseguir passar para você.

[image: Diferença de como as pessoas enxergam um projeto]

Comment: +1 até pq se for uma ação  cujo objeto seja consensual não tem réu, só partes interessadas.

Answer (score 0):

Sugestão :

```
Tabela Processo
Id
Id_Pessoa  -Traz a pessoa
Id_TipoPessoa -Traz que tipo de participação ela terá nesse processo

Tabela Pessoa
Id
Nome


Tabela TipoPessoa
Id
Descricao (réu,cliente,autor)
```