# Quantas tabelas serão necessárias no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Estou começando um projeto que visa gerenciar notas e matérias dos alunos.

As informações que precisarei armazenar são:

- Matérias totais (Todas as matérias que o aluno precisará estudar)
- Matérias vigentes (São as matérias liberadas para o semestre, ex. 7)
- Notas Prova 1, Prova 2, Prova-Exame e Média
- Alunos (Nome completo e CPF)
- Datas das Provas

O correto seria organizar essas informações como? Criaria 5 tabelas e FK pra todo mundo? Depois puxaria cada item quando precisasse?

Tentei fazer com 2 tabelas, mas parece impossível...

Obs. Só preciso de como seria a boa prática, não precisam mandar o código, somente o modelo relacional mesmo.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

A parte mais difícil é coletar os requisitos e analisar profundamente o que precisa. Pode ser que você já fez isso bem, pode ser que não. Se não está bem feito, nós não temos como ajudar precisamente.

Algum motivo para criar o mínimo de tabelas possível? Não vejo razão e parece muito errado. EU já vi sistemas complexos inteiros em uma única tabela, foi ao mesmo tempo umas das coisas mais trágicas e cômicas que eu já vi em TI.

Conhece [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101)? Precisa conhecer para modelar tabelas de banco de dados.

Por cima, e não sei se isto é útil, seriam realmente as que destacou, mas só porque foi descrito assim:

- Alunos
- Disciplinas
- Disciplinas X Semestres
- Provas
- Notas

Estou considerando que só tem um curso e os semestres não possuem informações relevantes e são considerados implicitamente sem precisa de cadastro, a aplicação tratará disso.

Os dados serão obtidos de acordo com a normalização, em muitos casos usando `JOIN` considerando a FK. Na verdade este não parece ser um problema difícil de resolver, que exija algo excepcional, a não ser que a coleta de requisitos e análise esteja errada.

Falou de boa prática para a pessoa errada, eu odeio isso, e considero que causa um estrago na mente das pessoas, porque no fundo a pessoa quer uma receita de bolo universal que resolva o problema dela sem precisar pensar. Em desenvolvimento de software se isso existir não precisa contratar pessoas só pra aplicar isso, já teria tudo pronto. Tem que aprender os fundamentos, entender tudo como funciona, os contextos, analisar profundamente e aplicar cada conhecimento básico para encontrar a melhor solução para o problema específico dentro daquele contexto.

De qualquer forma é isto que dá para responder, o modelo depende e seria fazer para você, o código nem faria sentido porque nada indica que tenha código nisso. Por isso que não gosto de boas práticas, parece que a frase foi *formulesca*, não considerou o contexto.

Se tiver algum problema específico pode perguntar.

Comment: Maniero, sua resposta foi super completa. Na verdade eu estou tentando "resumir" algo que não deveria ser resumido, tentando economizar nas tabelas, e isso me prejudicaria até, caso esse projeto aumentasse. 

Li a explicação sobre Normalização, muito bacana, e me esclareceu.

Comentei sobre código, pois já tentei tirar essa duvida antes e confundiram com a codificação das tabelas. Devo estar me expressando errado. 

As informações que preciso são somente estas mesmo, algo simples e objetivo. 
Gostaria na vdd, apenas de saber como alguém mais experiente faria.
Muito obrigada!

Comment: @Flávia A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo