# Melhor forma para normalização de banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados, normalização

O que seria o melhor caminho a seguir com relação a normalização de dados? O sistema terá basicamente três tipos de "pessoas":

- Agência
- Colaborador
- Cliente

Estas entidades tem algumas propriedades comuns, por exemplo: Contatos, Endereço, número de documento, nome, usuário enfim.

Qual seria o melhor caminho a seguir do ponto de vista da normalização destas tabelas?

- Uma tabela para cada entidade? ou
- Uma tabela pessoa com os dados comuns a todos, e uma sub-tabela para cada especificidade?

Comment: Pesquise sobre particionamento. Você pode ter uma entidade pessoa com todos os dados comuns e relacionamentos globais e uma entidade derivada para cada tipo de pessoa com os dados particulares de cada tipo de pessoa bem como os relacionamentos particulares de cada tipo.

Comment: Ótimo, pesquisarei sim. é a forma que o colega abaixo sugeriu também e a que eu estava mais inclinado a utilizar. Muitíssimo obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sempre depende. Mas eu diria que o mais certo é uma entidade de `Pessoa` que pode até `PessoaFisica` e `PessoaJuridica` se achar interessante e ter outros objetos com papeis que essa pessoa exerce na sua organização. Quase sempre ter só os papéis com repetição dos meus dados da pessoa nessas entidades está errado por manter objetos diferentes no sistema para o mesmo objeto real.

A pessoa é um objeto claro e óbvio de qualquer modelo. Os dados dos papéis nem sempre são tão óbvios, temos que pensar nisto como documentos especiais, porque eles nem existem como objetos reais.

Então deveria ter tabelas de `Cliente`, `Colaborador`, `Fornecedor`, etc. até porque uma mesma pessoa pode ter mais de um papel.

Conceitualmente é o mais correto ter tudo separado. Se por razões de performance não quiser ter separado até poderia ter os papéis junto ao objeto da pessoa, mas isso não é universalmente mais interessante nem mesmo olhando só performance. Mas cada vez isto é menos necessário por causa de tecnologias que se comportam mais próximo de como é a memória. Principalmente em disco pode ter útil mater uma tabela só, mas não é fácil administrar isto.

Em memória geralmente teria que manter esses objetos separados e lá não tem muita vantagem juntar tudo.

Mas o que mais vale é o conceito correto, com ele dá para fazer qualquer que precisa de forma organizada e fácil, quando o conceito está errado toda manutenção se torna complicada ou quase impossível, a não ser por mudar tudo completamente.

O que quase sempre é errado é ter as tabelas dos papéis e não ter a pessoa relacionada, ou seja, repetir a mesma pessoa em todas tabelas, como quase todos os sistemas fazem, uma pena.

Veja [O que é normalização de banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101).

Comment: Concordo, justamente por isso recorri a comunidade, e apesar de tentar deixar o mais normalizado o possível sempre, não tenho tanta experiência com normalização, porém acho muito importante que este esteja coeso e simples de fazer a manutenção. Então a ideia de utilizar uma tabela pessoa com os dados básicos (id, nome, endereço -separado em outra tabela, claro- etc) e estender esta tabela para seus papeis específicos (agência, fornecedores, clientes, colaboradores etc), basicamente o conceito de particionamento (conforme sugestões dos comentários), seria o caminho correto a seguir neste caso?

Comment: Correto não posso dizer, modelar é usar a experiência e pegar profundamente o problema específico. Se fosse fórmula não precisa de tanto programador, todos os problemas já teriam uma solução. Eu faria assim em quase todos os casos.

Comment: Eu já havia pensado em fazer desta forma também, e até o momento as sugestões de todos os colegas indicam este caminho, creio que seja o melhor também.

Comment: Será que é recomendável utilizar esta mesma pergunta para mostrar a modelagem que a qual cheguei, para pedir a opinião dos caros colegas??

Comment: Se tem algo diferente para perguntar agora preciosa ser outra pergunta. E pedir opinião não é algo que seja aceito no site. Tem que ser algo objetivo.

Comment: OK, então encerro por aqui.. rs
Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo!

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso a melhor solução seria de fato a normalização, com tabelas interligando as colunas em comum, principalmente visando a manutenção. Imagine em um caso em que teria que ser feita uma alteração no formato dos dados de endereço, uma adição de coluna em relação ao cadastro de pessoa e etc, e isso deve ser feito da melhor e mais rápida forma possível. Em um caso não normalizado seriam três tabelas pra serem alteradas e depois revisadas e, no pior caso, corrigidas caso algo tenha dado errado, e assim por diante. Sem contar na escalabilidade, que em caso de um banco de dados muito populado, o gerenciamento e a manutenção fica muito mais simples e segura com uma base de dados normalizada.

Em um nível bem aplicado de normalização, haveria uma tabela para dados de pessoa, como número de documentação, nome e etc e essa tabela seria referenciada por tabelas de agencia, colaborador e cliente, considerando que uma mesma pessoa poderia ser colaboradora e cliente ao mesmo tempo, evitando a redundância exagerada de dados.

A utilidade de se ter os dados de colaborador, por exemplo, em uma tabela separada é a vantagem de que isso pode fornecer uma filtragem e uma faixa maior de detalhamento dos dados, como, por exemplo, datas de início e de fim de vínculo de pessoa-colaborado.

Comment: A minha dúvida era justamente com relação a seu último parágrafo, realmente para mim fazia mais sentido assim, o endereço e o usuário, por exemplo, eu já faço separados, incluso sendo o endereço dividido em duas partes uma com um cadastro genérico de logradouros (onde um cep não aparece mais do que uma vez, a menos que seja cep único para a cidade) e uma segunda tabela onde armazeno a especificidade do endereço (número e complemento) para o cadastro. Mas estou realmente inclinado a fazer o cadastro das pessoas da forma como mencionou. Ou seja, uma tabela Pessoa, com dados básicos, e a estender

Comment: Isso não é de fato uma regra, mas tenha em mente que em uma base normalizada, a manutenção e o gerenciamento ficam melhores e mais objetivos, afinal, ao invés de corrigir ou alterar o tamanho de um campo de endereço em três tabelas, por exemplo, será em apenas uma.

Comment: Sim, concordo contigo, e é justamente nisso que estou pensando, esse sistema não é de cliente, é meu, estou querendo fazer ele para ser um sistema de prateleira, e de preferência com a manutenção o mais fácil o possível, rs