# Como pegar todas as informações do $_POST

Tags: php, array, post

Tenho uma array enviada pelo $_POST:

```
array(4) {
            ["gabarito"]=> string(1) "4"
            ["resposta1"]=> string(1) "A"
            ["resposta2"]=> string(1) "B"
            ["resposta3"]=> string(1) "A"
       }
```

Eu precisa pegar essas informações para fazer um INSERT no MYSQL, mas não sei como faço para pegar o nome do $_POST (por exemplo: "gabarito"). O resultado final deverá ser:

```
(gabarito, resposta1, resposta2, resposta3)
values
(4,A,B,A)
```

Tendo em vista que essa array é variavel, ela pode ter 4 itens, 10, 50, varios, então precisaria ser de uma forma dinamica

O que pensei foi a opção abaixo, porém não sei como pegar o nome do $_POST (é assim que fala? ainda sou iniciante, em $_POST['reposta1'] o resposta1 é nome? parâmetro?)

fiz da seguinte forma:

```
foreach($_POST as $resposta){
    $resposta.=',';
    $respostas .= $resposta;
}
echo '('.$respostas.')';
```

Aí isso resulta em (4,A,B,A,)

Comment: Pesquise pelas funções `array_keys` e `array_values`, acredito que te ajudará. Também a `implode`, ou `join`, já adiantando na hora de converter de *array* para *string*.

Comment: Os nomes das colunas na tabela mudam? n pode passar `$_POST['resposta1'] .... ` ?

Comment: os nomes são sempre os mesmo, mas as vezes pode ter só resposta1 e reposta2 e outra pode ter até 150 respostas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pensou bem, só faltou adicionar as chaves:

```
$_POST = [
    "gabarito" => "4",
    "resposta1" => "A",
    "resposta2" => "B",
    "resposta3" => "A"
];

$into = "";
$values = "";

foreach ($_POST as $chave => $valor) {
    $into .= "$chave, ";
    $values .= "'$valor', ";
}

//Retira o último ', '
$into = trim($into, ", ");
$values = trim($values, ", ");

echo "INSERT INTO ($into) VALUES ($values)";
```

Mas esse código tem o problema de SQL Injection, que pode ser facilmente resolvido com [real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Uma outra solução, que considero melhor é usar as funções nativas do php:

```
echo "INSERT INTO tabela (".implode(", ", array_keys($_POST)).") VALUES ('".implode("', '", $_POST)."')";
```

**Importante:**

Apesar de funcionar usar várias colunas dessa forma não é muito recomendado, sugiro criar uma outra tabela que se relacione com a que já existe. Sugiro dar uma olhada nas [Formas normais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323)

Comment: perfeit, deu certinho!

Comment: De uma olhada nesse meu último parágrafo e principalmente na pergunta linkada

Answer (score 0):

Bem, você pensou bem em usar o `foreach`, porém, ao mesmo tempo você está puxando de uma `array`, então recomendo que faça assim:

```
$_POST = array('gabarito' => array('resposta1' => 'A', 'resposta2' => 'B', 'resposta3' => 'C'));
```

Tendo sua variável `$_POST` dessa maneira, ficará mais fácil para você agora montar o que realmente você deseja, que no caso é mostrar a resposta do gabarito em questão. Mandaremos para o `foreach` o seu gabarito:

```
$_POST = array('gabarito' => array('resposta1' => 'A', 'resposta2' => 'B', 'resposta3' => 'C'));
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data = "{$key} = ".implode(', ', $value);
}
echo $data;
```

Bom, eu faria assim, automaticamente você possuirá este resultado:

```
gabarito = A, B, C
```

Outro método já colocando no `INSERT INTO` seria assim:

```
$_POST = array('gabarito' => array('resposta1' => 'A', 'resposta2' => 'B', 'resposta3' => 'C'));
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $questao = $key;
    $respostas = implode(', ', $value);
}
echo 'INSERT INTO tabela (ID, GABARITO, RESPOSTA1, RESPOSTA2, RESPOSTA3) VALUES (NULL, '.$questao.', '.$respostas.')';
```

Bom, um exemplo de como fazer isso na prática é assim olha:

```
$quest = 4;
$resp = array('a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C');
$_POST = array($quest => array('resposta1' => $resp['a'], 'resposta2' => $resp['b'], 'resposta3' => $resp['c']));
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $questao = $key;
    $respostas = implode(', ', $value);
}
echo 'INSERT INTO tabela (ID, GABARITO, RESPOSTA1, RESPOSTA2, RESPOSTA3) VALUES (NULL, '.$questao.', '.$respostas.')';
```

Pois assim, você configura seu `foreach` e sua `array` da sua maneira, agora se você usar um código com apenas um estilo padrão, demorará mais para você na hora que quiser adaptar ou transferir o método. Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score -1):

Use foreach:

```
# v2
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

ele vai iterar em cima de **TODAS** as key de $_POST

Edit: você tem razão, o código acima não funcionava

Comment: deu um erro: Warning: Illegal string offset 'gabarito' in ...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você tem razão, eu tava viajando na maionese, arrumei o código, o certo é $_POST[$key] sendo $value o valor da variável, desculpem a gafe

Comment: Ao invés de "_interar_", acho que o correto seria "**iterar**", não?

Comment: coloco inteiramente a culpa no meu corretor, mas vc tem razão, agradeço

Comment: A sua resposta pode responder a pergunta, porém esta muito vaga, tente ser mais completo