# Lógica com endereços em php

Tags: pdo, lógica, php-7, cep

estou fazendo um cadastro de lojas em um site de classificados, onde o usuário pegaria o endereço da loja através do viacep e junto com os dados daria um insert no bd.

tabela "anuncios" ficaria parecida com algo como:

**id | nome_local | usuario_id | cep | rua | bairro | cidade | numero | data_envio | imagem | categoria_id**

Essa modelagem é correta, visto que posso conter muitas colunas, sem falar no número de cadastros que essa tabela pode ter. Visando performance.

Mas teria como reaproveitar esses dados de endereço caso outra pessoa cadastre uma loja no mesmo cep?

E se eu separar os dados de endereço em outra tabela, é viável? Queria ter mais controle nesses dados, poder dar uma descrição para a cidade, fazer uma busca mais otimizada por cep e etc. Só que me preocupa, **caso o usuário atualize o cadastro da sua loja e mude o cep que pode ter varias lojas.**

Me dêem uma luz, pelo texto nota que estou bem perdido.

Comment: Todas as respostas dependem diretamente dos requisitos da sua aplicação. Você já fez a lista de requisitos?

Comment: Não necessariamente, preciso saber qual melhor método levando em conta performance desse tipo de cadastro.

Comment: Performance em quais pontos? Velocidade ou memória?

Comment: Velocidade, consultas rápidas. MInha dúvida é se colocar todos os dados correspondente ao endereço na tabela com os dados do anuncio não deixaria mais lento essas consultas. E se fosse possível reaproveitar endereços.

Comment: A quantidade de dados impactará muito menos do que fazer o banco bem estruturado. Recomendo que leia sobre [normalização de bancos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/5878), isso provavelmente responderá essa e possivelmente muitas outras dúvidas que possui. Se deixar da maneira que está sua tabela não estará normalizada, pois tem dados de endereço associadas a dados do usuário. Nem sempre isso é ruim, depende dos requisitos, mas de qualquer forma assim não será possível reaproveitar o CEP, pois depende do id do usuário.

Comment: Dica: não tome o CEP como um referencial fixo. As faixas de CEPs estão sempre em constante mudança e podem ser alterados várias vezes para um mesmo endereço. Se o seu banco não for consistente, poderá, inclusive, ter CEPs duplicados com endereços distintos.

Comment: Fiz uma breve leitura do artigo (estudarei bem mais tarde). Correto seria criar uma tabela endereços e linkar com "endereco_id" na tabela do local, sendo ele único para cada local. Repetir o endereço nessa tabela não será errado desde que possua id único. Correto?

Comment: Uma tabela que chama `anuncios`e tem um endereço parece errado. Não posso garantir porque não conheço o problema, ele não está claro. Dá margem pra considerar que é opinião falar sobre isso, mas ainda acho que é mais não clara. Ter muitas colunas ou linhas não é problema, não sei porque as pessoas se preocupam com isso. Então deverria modelar diferentemente p/ ficar + correto, só não temos como afirmar como sem entender profundamente o problema. Eu quase fechei como não clara,mas acabei optando por fora de escopo porque no sites resolvemos problemas específicos,dar uma luza não está no escopo.

Comment: Agradeço Maniero, realmente, não consegui passar meu pensamento, mas sua resposta como a do Anderson me tranquilizam quanto ao numero de colunas. A soluçao que encontrei com suas respotas é que farei uma tabela anuncio e outra endereço, sendo que vou cadastrar o anuncio junto com endereço, dai vou referenciar com um campo na tabela anuncio, sendo que endereço vai ser unico apra cada anuncio mesmo que tenha o mesmo nome. Valeu pela ajuda.