# Detalhes de pagamento parcelado de apólices de seguro

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-html, entidade-relacionamento, pagamento-online

Estou encontrando dificuldades em modelar uma entidade "Detalhes de Pagamento", onde conste a numeração de uma apólice ou endosso de seguros, com informações como prêmio bruto a pagar, IOF, custo total, etc. e mais o parcelamento, que pode ser em até 3 vezes.

Minha dificuldade é justamente como modelar o parcelamento. Eu teria que ter uma linha para cada parcela?

A PK desta entidade é a numeração da apólice que é única, porém se eu parcelar, ela deixará de ser única, pois terei repetição.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que deu para entender você terá duas tabelas (é possível que tenha outras, mas não para esta parte do problema), uma com os detalhes gerais do pagamento e outra para as parcelas. Até tem como fazer de outra forma, mas é mais avançado e mais como otimização e complicado em alguns sistemas, então o modelo relacional [normalizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151323/101) mais coreto seria assim.

Nessa tabela de parcelas teria uma linha para cada parcela. A chave primária seria composta pelo número da apólice mais um serial de item, então a primeira parcela teria o serial 01, a segunda, 02, e assim por diante. Os dois campos juntos formam sempre uma chave única.

Obviamente será comum usar `JOIN` para juntar as duas informações.

Comment: Na verdade os detalhes da entidade "DetalhesDePagamento", descendem de uma entidade chamada "DetalhesDaEmissão". 
O que está sugerindo é na entidade "DetalhesDePagamento" eu realizar um JOIN dos atributos "Parcela" e "Documento(Apólice) para a criação de uma chave primária?
DetalhesEmissao
Apólice (PK)
Seguradora
Processo
Inicio de Vigencia
Fim de VIgencia
Importância Segurada(R$)
Prêmio Total

DetalheDePagamento
CodPagamento(JOIN "Documento" + Parcela)PK
Apolice(FK)
Parcela
Custo Total
IOF
Premio Líquido
Premio Bruto
FormaDePagamento
Parcela
O relacionamento seria (1,n)