# Formas de implementar "abertura" de dia para liberar inserção de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou com uma página que faz a coleta de informações da equipe de vendas, com dados do cliente, dados da concorrência, etc. Segue código:

```
CREATE TABLE dados_relatorio(
    id int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    codigo int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    data_1 date NOT NULL,
    vendedor varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    supervisor varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    cidade varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    uf varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    razao varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    ramo varchar(35) NOT NULL,
    posicionamento varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    limpeza varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    layout varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    visibilidade varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    visibilidade_i varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    materiais varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    equipamento smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    qtd_equipamento smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    tabela varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    cat_real smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_premium smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_paleta smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_frutas smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_infantil smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_acai smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_mono smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    cat_outro smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
    dividido varchar(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Acontece que a gerência quer que seja vinculado a quilometragem do dia, porém esses dados deverão vir no seguinte formato: O vendedor "abre" o dia no sistema, insere a quilometragem, após isso, o sistema libera para receber os dados e inserir no banco de dados. Ao final do dia, "fecha-se" o dia com a quilometragem final.
Hoje, após o login do vendedor, ele insere a data da visita, e faz a coleta dos dados. Pensei em criar outra tabela para inserir as datas e quilometragem, e depois fazer algum tipo de condicional, mas achei que era uma abordagem longa para chegar nesse objetivo.

Existe alguma alternativa "mais" viável? Pois cada vendedor terá que fazer essa "abertura" do dia com a quilometragem inicial e fechar o dia com a quilometragem final, e ele só poderá dar entrada nos dados se for realizado essa abertura, e consequentemente, o novo dia também irá requerer o fechamento do último....
Caso essa seja a melhor abordagem, vou entrar de cabeça, mas se houver outra que acharem melhor, ficarei grato.

Obrigado.

Comment: **Pensei em criar outra tabela para inserir as datas e quilometragem"* iss me parece, com os dados que tem na pergunta, a melhor opição, uma tabela que tenha a data e FK  com vendedor, que pode ter duas colunas `KMAbertura` e `KMFechamento`. Isso vai fazer precisar de um INSERT e depois um UPDATE, mas tem uma vantagem, ao logar verifica se tem linha nessa tabela para o vendedor/data, se não tiver pede, se já tiver, deixa mandar dados. Se quiser mais detalhes avise que posso por numa resposta

Comment: Ei @RicardoPontual. Entendi. Se puder acrescentar detalhes, ficaria grato. Eu ficaria grato se pudesse explicar melhor como o FK funcionaria nesse caso. Eu entendo que ele depende da PK da outra tabela, mas a dinâmica confesso que não peguei 100%. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro vou responder a pergunta, a seguir abordo o comentário, que é um pouco diferente do que está na pergunta.

A modelagem poderia ser por exemplo assim:

```
CREATE TABLE dados_fechamento(  
    id int(4) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    data date NOT NULL,
    vendedor varchar(45) NOT NULL, 
    valor_abertura INT NOT NULL,
    valor_fechamento INT
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Eu copiei a coluna "vendedor" da tabela "dados_relatorio", mas isso não está normalizado corretamente, deveria existir uma entidade "vendedor" com atributos só do vendedor (id, nome por exemplo) e usar uma chave estrangeira, mas para não misturar com o escopo da pergunta, vamos deixar assim pra já.

Essa tabela "dados_fechamento" vai armazenar os dados de KM, tem o vendedor (nome, portanto desnormalizado), a data e valores abertura e fechamento.

Então, ao fazer o login, pesquise o vendedor nessa tabela trazendo o registro mais recente, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM dados_fechamento 
 WHERE vendedor = 'nome do vendedor'
 ORDER BY data DESC
```

Com esse resultado, qual seria a lógica:

- não tem resultados, então é a primeira vez que usa essa tabela, pede o valor_abertura e faz um INSERT;
- tem resultados, mas a data é diferente de hoje, pede o valor_abertura e faz um INSERT. Pode também pedir o valor de fechamento da data anterior e fazer UPDATE:
- tem resultados e a data é de hoje, então já lançou valor de abertura, pode seguir o código ou perguntar se quer lançar o fechamento. Se informar o fechamento, faz UPDATE.

Sobre o comentário *"Eu ficaria grato se pudesse explicar melhor como o FK funcionaria nesse caso"*, precisa normalizar a tabela **dados_relatorio**, ou seja, aplicar as **formas normais de normalização**, por exemplo extrair as entidades vendedor, supervisor e cidade, mas isso é melhor ter outra pergunta, pois é outro escopo.

Comment: Ei Ricardo, obrigado pela explicação e pela ideia. Vou buscar implementar a normalização das tabelas.

Comment: boa, se tiver dúvidas por por uma pergunta, e leia essa outra pergunta aqui do site, muito boa e completa sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/151323/o-que-%c3%a9-normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-banco-de-dados